# git: Unable to index file - permission denied

Tags: git, indexing, addition

Only for one file, I am getting the following error:

```
error: unable to write sha1 filename /opt/www/.git/objects/3f/ce3587c54a8be14c69b08c6b01f94949b11b47: Permission denied

error: wp/wp-admin/css/theme-install.dev.css: failed to insert into database
fatal: unable to index file wp/wp-admin/css/theme-install.dev.css
```

I checked my permissions on the file in question, the **.git** objects directory in question, and **.git** itself. I can add any other files except for this one. I could `stat/r/w/touch` the file, and touching did not help. The **permissions** are all correct.

Is this some crazy bug?

Comment: Can you `touch` new files in `.../objects/3f`, or if not, what is its mode? Does `.../objects/3f/ce3...` already exist, and if so, what is its mode? Could the partition where `/opt` lives be full?

Comment: Touching is fine, and the file does not exist.

Comment: also happened to me in this case : having a file named "imafile"
> removing this file > create a directory named "imafile" > put files in = can't commit because "Unable to find index"

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Looking at the Git source code (`sha1_file.c`, function `move_temp_to_file()`) it looks like Git is failing to rename a temporary file named `/opt/www/.git/objects/3f/tmp_obj_XXXXXX` (where `XXXXXX` is six random characters) to `/opt/www/.git/objects/3f/ce3587c54a8be14c69b08c6b01f94949b11b47`.  This can happen if you don't have permission to delete files in `/opt/www/.git/objects/3f`.

Some things to try:

- If multiple users accessing the Git repository, you may need to run something like `git config core.sharedRepository 0664` (see `git help config` for details) to ensure that newly created directories and files have proper permissions for all users of the repository.
- Try running `rm -f /opt/www/.git/objects/3f/tmp_obj_*` and see if that makes the problem go away.
- See if you can reproduce the problem outside of Git by doing the following:

  ```
  mkdir -p /opt/www/.git/objects/3f
  cd /opt/www/.git/objects/3f
  rm -f tmp_obj_* ce3587c54a8be14c69b08c6b01f94949b11b47
  echo "testing" >tmp_obj_abcdefg
  mv tmp_obj_abcdef ce3587c54a8be14c69b08c6b01f94949b11b47
  rm -f tmp_obj_abcdefg
  ```

  Be sure to run the above commands the same user that experienced the error.
- Try recursively `chown`ing and `chmod`ing the objects directory.

Comment: For an unknown reason, I indeed had some objects own by root.

Answer (score 76):

If you are using visual studio or something similar that is generating the mdf file, simply close VS & retry your git command again. This time it should work.

To save constantly closing & reopening, you should add references into .gitignore file in the project root. For example, if it is a database causing the issue, add the following:

```
# SQL Server files
*.mdf
*.ldf
```

Comment: This worked for me. I was having the problem by trying to commit a Unity project with VS open. Closed it and the error went away.

Comment: This is extremely frustrating, because it means I cannot use Team Explorer to manage my code. I have to make the required changes in Visual Studioo, close the application, commit my changes, open up the application and resume working. There must be a way around this.

Comment: Klicker, put whatever file is causing it in the ignore file like I suggested with *.mdf etc above. That will do the trick.

Comment: Worked for me. Just closed VS and ran the `git add` command and was able to go through with committing.

Comment: I just closed the Visual Studio 2022. And then commit and push via Git Bash, it worked fine for me.

Comment: It fixed temporarily. It appears again. Permanent solution is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42667928/visual-studio-2017-git-failed-with-a-fatal-error. Delete visual studio git credentials from windows credential manager.

Comment: I closed Visual Studio 2022 and added the files via `git add .` in the external terminal app downloaded from the Windows store and it worked.

Answer (score 19):

Just close the Visual Studio (or Unity) and try to add those files again.

Comment: I've closed the nodeJs server where my angularJs app was running and the index was unlocked.

Comment: that works, but suppose I have 4 projects open at one point of time, I can't close all four of them just to add files to git. Isn't there any other solution that doesn't require closing it ?

Comment: Yea, Its works when u do lock it  with Visual Studio

Answer (score 10):

You don't have permission to write in `/opt/www/.git/objects/3f`.

The quickest solution is to use the `sudo` command to execute your command with root privileges.

`sudo <Your git command>`

Solved it for me.

Comment: worked for me... I think what caused it in my case was aborting halfway through a previous commit

Answer (score 5):

Something has gone awry in your git repository likely caused by an external process creating a file or directory which is owned by a user other than the current user.

This error is common when using Docker, and a service in your docker-compose.yml file has a locally mounted volume which was created using a different user to that of the local machine user.

If this is the first time that this error has occurred, execute the below on your working directory to change the ownership of files and folders back to the logged in user:

```
sudo chown -R ${USER}:${USER} .
```

If this is not the first time you have encountered this issue, i.e. you have already committed and pushed files and folders that are owned by another user, then the above alone will not rectify the situation, as well as executing the above command - you will need to carry out the following instructions.

By far, the quickest fix is to execute the following from your root project directory which holds your git repository:

```
sudo chown -R ${USER}:${USER} .git/objects
```

To test that everything is fixed, execute the following:

```
git add .
```

Quickly followed by executing:

```
git status
```

You will see that everything has been added to the git repository without any need to test / fiddle around with anything any further.

Comment: This is the correct solution, if you've used `sudo` with git commands some permissions will be changed in the .git folder, which creates this error

Answer (score 3):

```
error: open("3/BasicMVVM/.vs/BasicMVVM/v16/Server/sqlite3/db.lock"): Permission denied
```

error: unable to index file 3/BasicMVVM/.vs/BasicMVVM/v16/Server/sqlite3/db.lock
fatal: adding files failed

if you have such error and you are working on visual studio.first you close the visual studio. git bash and write "git add * " with out inverted commas and on the suitable place 
it will work for my self

Comment: your answer is not more clear. Please check is it helpful

Answer (score 0):

I was having this problem on my bare origin repository when the permissions were root:git 770, apparently I had to change it to 771, even though my user is in the git group. I suspect perhaps git is perhaps either not acl-aware, or not so compatible with secondary groups, as the git group was one of my secondary groups in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I stopped running my `Driver.main()` method in intelliJ (for java programming) and was able to add all my files to staging area with `git add .` command. Also try restarting intelliJ or whatever tool you are using for writing code as a second option.

Answer (score 0):

This happens to me when I was trying to push a doc file to GIT hub when it was opened. After closing it and tried the same and successfully pushed.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).