# Ubuntu 16.04 - > ERROR: Couldn't connect to Docker daemon - you might need to run `docker-machine start default`

Tags: ubuntu, docker-compose

I am getting error on ubuntu 16.04

> "ERROR: Couldn't connect to Docker daemon - you might need to run
>   `docker-    machine start default`. "

when i run following command

```
sudo docker-compose up
```

Can any one answer ?

Comment: It sounds like Compose failed to connect to the docker daemon. Is it running?

Comment: Same problem in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

Comment: that answer was a solution for me https://stackoverflow.com/a/46329423/11604316

Answer (score 39):

assuming your environment variables are set using the following shell command :

```
eval "$(docker-machine env default)"
```

then you can find the exact error by running the following shell command:

```
docker-compose --verbose up -d
```

many times its a proxy issue or if your running it with charles proxy it can block compose from connecting etc. if it is a proxy issue you can add this to your profile:

```
export no_proxy=192.168.99.100
```

Comment: The `docker-compose --verbose up -d` gives a lot of useful information

Comment: @Chococroc - The same error, I am getting with for Windows-10. How to solve this issues?

Answer (score 33):

If you installed Docker as a `snap` package try this:

```
sudo snap start docker
```

Comment: Not helped. Daemon is constantly inactive.

Comment: It says "Started" after I run this command. After that when I run ```docker-compose build``` , the error still shows up.

Comment: Sorry guys for who it didn't help.... I tried it on 10 computer in my office and it worked perfectly...

Comment: When I start the snap service, I can select docker or docker.dockerd. Both do not work, dockerd and containerd run as processes. Should I post the flags for both processes sraping from ps -ef?

Comment: It worked for me but I have to run `docker-compose up` with `sudo`

Comment: helped, just try with sudo

Answer (score 17):

> Starting the Docker daemon

Use following command :

```
sudo systemctl start docker
```

or on older distributions, you may need to use:

```
sudo service docker start
```

Answer (score 12):

You should add your user in docker group.
And then, you can use docker command without 'sudo'.

```
$ sudo usermod -aG docker ${USER}
$ sudo service docker restart
```

Next, you have to logout in your OS.
Finally, when you login, you can use docker command without 'sudo'.

Comment: This practice is considered a high security risk, please refer to the following link for a full description: https://www.zopyx.com/andreas-jung/contents/on-docker-security-docker-group-considered-harmful

Comment: @Matt G: It worked for me but how to avoid the risk

Comment: user2994783 what I suggest is to create a dedicated user and group in the image itself, with minimal
permissions - [principle of least privelege](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege) - to run the application, and use the same user to run this process. Another suggestion, although not a silver bullet, is to run a static analysis solution on your configuration to mitigate some of the security vulnerabilities.

Comment: @user2994783 you can check the document, [Handling Permissions With Docker Volumes](https://denibertovic.com/posts/handling-permissions-with-docker-volumes/) which discusses and details how to explicitly create a user inside a container to honour the principle of least privilege.

Answer (score 10):

You don't need to think much. Run the command with sudo previlage.

```
sudo docker-compose up -d --build
```

Answer (score 6):

After

```
#sudo snap remove docker //only if required
sudo snap install docker
```

Following command worked for me

```
docker-compose --verbose up -d
```

In case docker service is not active, please do any of the following (give priority to first one)

```
1. sudo snap start docker    
2. sudo systemctl start docker
3 .sudo service docker start
```

Answer (score 5):

After installing can execute command to have access to docker functionality without sudo. In my sitation, with same errors all is resolved after :

```
$ sudo usermod -aG docker ${USER}
$ su - ${USER}
$ id -n
$ sudo usermod -aG docker username
```

and can restart docker after that:

```
systemctl restart docker
```

Answer (score 5):

Running
**$sudo docker compose up -d**
resolved my issue.
Actually mine is permissions issue which I came to know by providing verbose option.

Comment: yeah sudo worked for me...

Answer (score 4):

Try running with root:
sudo docker-compose build

Answer (score 4):

We need to restart the docker

```
$ sudo service docker restart
```

[click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Fjct.png)

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes, this error appears if you built stack before.
Reason of giving error is migh be file permissions.
If in building process docker generates new files or edits some files, there will be some root owned files.

So, if the reason is permissions, make your user the owner of all application files.

```
$ sudo chown -R ${USER} .
```

Answer (score 2):

I had this same error 10 minutes ago and solved it by doing:

```
sudo snap remove docker
```

when finished:

```
sudo snap install docker
```

Problem solved.

Answer (score 2):

Use "sudo" privilege as prefix in all of your 'docker-compose' terminal commands.

Comment: This is generally frowned upon as a bad practice and opens up potential attack vectors if used in production

Answer (score 1):

in my case , sometime you just need to use "sudo docker-compose up"

Comment: This is the exact command that the original question states that produce the error!

Comment: My case is a permission issue，But see the same exception；here have same issue https://stackoverflow.com/a/63876990/11797177

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing this

```
asif@ck ~/u/m/moberry_pizza_order (main)> docker-compose -f local.yml build
ERROR: Couldn't connect to Docker daemon - you might need to run `docker-machine start default`.
asif@ck ~/u/m/moberry_pizza_order (main) [1]> docker-machine start default
Docker machine "default" does not exist. Use "docker-machine ls" to list machines. Use "docker-machine create" to add a new one.
asif@ck ~/u/m/moberry_pizza_order (main) [1]> docker-machine ls
NAME   ACTIVE   DRIVER   STATE   URL   SWARM   DOCKER   ERRORS
asif@ck ~/u/m/moberry_pizza_order (main)> docker-machine create -d dev;
Driver "dev" not found. Do you have the plugin binary "docker-machine-driver-dev" accessible in your PATH?
asif@ck ~/u/m/moberry_pizza_order (main) [1]> docker-compose -f local.yml up
ERROR: Couldn't connect to Docker daemon - you might need to run `docker-machine start default`.
```

Then I tried following,

```
$ sudo apt update && sudo apt dist-upgrade
$ docker-compose --version
docker-compose version 1.25.5, build unknown
$ sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
$ newgrp docker
$ docker run hello-world
```

Unable to find image 'hello-world:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from library/hello-world
b8dfde127a29: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:f2266cbfc127c960fd30e76b7c792dc23b588c0db76233517e1891a4e357d519
Status: Downloaded newer image for hello-world:latest

Hello from Docker!
This message shows that your installation appears to be working correctly.

To generate this message, Docker took the following steps:

1. The Docker client contacted the Docker daemon.
2. The Docker daemon pulled the "hello-world" image from the Docker Hub.
   (amd64)
3. The Docker daemon created a new container from that image which runs the
   executable that produces the output you are currently reading.
4. The Docker daemon streamed that output to the Docker client, which sent it
   to your terminal.

To try something more ambitious, you can run an Ubuntu container with:

```
 $ docker run -it ubuntu bash
```

After doing those my command start working

```
 $docker-compose -f local.yml up
```

Creating network "moberry_pizza_order_default" with the default driver
Creating volume "moberry_pizza_order_local_postgres_data" with default driver
Creating volume "moberry_pizza_order_local_postgres_data_backups" with default driver
Building postgres
Step 1/4 : FROM postgres:13.2
13.2: Pulling from library/postgres

So restarting the daemon is the main thing here. you can do it several ways.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that I got this error after installing docker-compose. Trying to run`sudo docker-compose build` gave me the error --

> ERROR: Couldn't connect to Docker daemon. You might need to install Docker

I solved this by [installing docker-ce](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-docker-on-ubuntu-16-04) (Ubuntu 16.04 and 18.04). Everything worked as expected thereafter

Answer (score 0):

In my particular case the mysql service specified in my docker-compose.yml file had created a volume named `mysql_data` in the project root directory. The problem is that this directory, and the contained files had been created with the user 999, and group of docker. So, we have essentially created ourselves a permissions issue which can be mitigated all together by using the techniques discussed in [Handling Permissions With Docker Volumes](https://denibertovic.com/posts/handling-permissions-with-docker-volumes/)

To remedy the immediate situation, however, you should determine what volume's data is causing the issue. In my particular case it was the `mysql_data` volume, so I executed the following, in the project root directory, to change file and directory ownership to that of the currently logged in user:

```
sudo chown -R ${USER}:${USER} mysql_data
```

If you are unsure which volume is causing the ownership related issue, to ensure that all of your project's ownership details are the same, you should execute the following in your project root directory:

```
sudo chown -R ${USER}:${USER} .
```

Now, if your project is under Git source code control, as a result of executing one of the above commands, you will now have a situation whereby file and directory ownership differs to that of the ownership in git stored objects database. You will most likely encounter errors similar to, "[git: Unable to index file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6400755/git-unable-to-index-file-permission-denied/51980628#51980628)", in which case - prior to the further adding and committing of any files to your git project repository, you should ensure that the ownership of the files in the git objects database are an exact mirror of your project's file ownership. You can ensure this by executing the following in the project root:

```
sudo chown -R ${USER}:${USER} .git/objects
```

Having now fixed the initial errors you encountered, you can now issue your original docker-compose command, that originally resulted in the "Couldn't Connect to Docker Daemon" error, successfully.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that I was missing **$** sign in front of variable in the image name

```
image: imagename:{TAG:-develop-latest}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Windows 10 and using Docker Toolbox use this

`& "C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker-machine.exe" env | Invoke-Expression`

Answer (score 0):

I had this error and did the unthinkable: I just rebooted my laptop. I was and am annoyed about it, but it took about 1 minute and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you installed docker from the snap store , you can start docker this way

```
sudo snap start docker
```

and then try this :

```
 sudo docker-compose up
```