# Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:/var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, docker, ubuntu-14.04

I have applied every solution available on internet but still I cannot run Docker.

I want to use Scrapy Splash on my server.

Here is `history` of commands I ran.

```
docker run -p 8050:8050 scrapinghub/splash
sudo docker run -p 8050:8050 scrapinghub/splash
sudo usermod -aG docker $(whoami)
sudo docker run -p 8050:8050 scrapinghub/splash
newgrp docker
sudo docker run -p 8050:8050 scrapinghub/splash
reboot
sudo docker run -p 8050:8050 scrapinghub/splash
docker run -p 8050:8050 scrapinghub/splash
```

You can see I tried to restart my server as well, but it didnt help.

see output of `ps -aux | grep docker`

```
root@mani:/var/www/html# ps aux | grep docker
root      8524  0.0  0.8 127904 13964 ?        Ssl  17:21   0:00 /usr/bin/dockerd --raw-logs
root      8534  0.0  0.3  90588  5012 ?        Ssl  17:21   0:00 docker-containerd -l unix:///var/run/docker/libcontainerd/docker-containerd.sock --metrics-interval=0 --start-timeout 2m --state-dir /var/run/docker/libcontainerd/containerd --shim docker-containerd-shim --runtime docker-runc
root      8543  0.0  0.0   8812   764 pts/1    S+   17:21   0:00 grep --color=auto docker
root     16356  0.0  0.0  17200   964 pts/1    S    17:14   0:00 newgrp docker
root     20080  0.0  0.0  17200   964 pts/1    S    17:06   0:00 newgrp docker
root     30221  0.0  0.0  17200   964 pts/1    S    17:09   0:00 newgrp docker
```

but it gives the error:

> Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at `unix:///var/run/docker.sock`. Is the docker daemon running?.

Comment: If you run ps aux | grep docker, do you see the daemon process running?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21871479/docker-cant-connect-to-docker-daemon?rq=1

Comment: @Rome_Leader see the output in my question ...

Comment: try this : 
sudo service docker restart

Comment: @HaythemROUIS no luck

Comment: you can see the status of you docker deamon using this :

`sudo service docker status`
check if it is active

Comment: Try `sudo systemctl restart docker`

Comment: @HaythemROUIS `docker start/running, process 25036`

Comment: What happens if you kill the currently running Docker PIDs with sudo kill -9 and then try to start the docker daemon from scratch as above?

Comment: if i do `sudo service docker start` then it shows `start: Job is already running: docker`

Comment: On Mac I just opened Docker UI app. It upgraded and done.

Comment: the problem may be because of your daemon.json file

Comment: Restarting my computer solved the problem for me (MacOS Mojave 10.14).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Docker can't connect to docker daemon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21871479/docker-cant-connect-to-docker-daemon)

Comment: consider accepting an answer....

Comment: In my case, my docker d

Comment: I got this error because I was running a shell INSIDE MY DOCKER CONTAINER!.  Open up another terminal and type `docker ps`.   Or simple type `exit` where you are and you'll likely hop out.

Comment: Just to clarify your problem has no relation with scrapinghub/splash or any specific image you used. It's likely fresh setup you had and it just needed restart to make it work! :) 2 cents to avoid confusion.

Comment: For wsl2 and Ubuntu Desktop refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72617404/3429457

Comment: On a Centos 7 machine I solved with this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1338819/docker-after-21-04-update-runninng-on-run-docker-sock

Comment: Just open docker desktop application. Worked for me.

Answer (score 584):

You can try out this:

```
systemctl start docker
```

It worked fine for me.

P.S.: after if there is commands that you can't do without sudo, try this:

```
gpasswd -a $USER docker
```

Comment: Running first command, I got an error:  `Failed to start docker.service: Unit docker.service is masked.`
So, I had to run following:  
`systemctl unmask docker.service`
`systemctl unmask docker.socket` 
`systemctl start docker.service`

Comment: If you got docker through snap, do `docker.help` And follow the steps. Refer to https://askubuntu.com/questions/977961/unit-docker-service-could-not-be-found#978012

Comment: ```sudo service docker start
 * Starting Docker: docker``` was the fix for me.

Comment: @AlejandroArmas suggestion worked for me too.

Comment: Neither `systemctl start docker` nor `sudo service docker start` worked for me, on Ubuntu 22.04 -- I still get the same error message.

Comment: When I ran `systemctl start docker` I got
`System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.`.

Comment: This is due to the fact that you're trying to run this command in a distro (or an alpine container, for example) that does not use systemd as a "process manager". systemctl is a command from systemd, so that does not work. What's your environnement ?

Comment: For this error using the WSL "When I ran systemctl start docker I got System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate."

I fixed by installing "https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/releases/download/1.0.3/Microsoft.WSL_1.0.3.0_x64_ARM64.msixbundle"

From :  https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/releases

Comment: **systemctl** doesn't work on MacBook.

Comment: @CesarCisneros thanks for mentioning that, helped me fix an issue I was struggling with

Comment: For WSL *******UNDER DOCKER DESKTOP *******  Resources --> WSL Integration
     Enable integration with my default WSL distro and Enable integration with additional distros

Comment: I don't know `gpasswd`, I then used `sudo usermod -aG docker $USER` to add current user to docker group, also I needed to have docker service started on boot I then have also run `sudo systemctl enable docker` to achieve it. And thanks by the way ;)

Comment: this is `launchctl start docker` on mac fyi

Answer (score 393):

Just Run

```
sudo dockerd
```

dockerd is the daemon service for docker containers, because it is not running in background we're not able to take any actions related to the service, which needs be restarted.

Comment: It gives me error `Error starting daemon: Devices cgroup isn't mounted`

Comment: @fepegar Possibly you're not having docker installed properly

Comment: @YashPokar indeed, I ended up reinstalling and now things work as expected. Thanks.

Comment: Only command that works for me inside a docker container to start a docker container. Need it for codebuild, to create my own environment while building. :-)

Comment: I use Rasperry 3 B with debian 9 and get: `failed to mount overlay:no such device. aufs was not found in /proc/filesystems and again failed to mount overlay`. `apt install docker-compose` did not work, I followed [this](https://dev.to/rohansawant/installing-docker-and-docker-compose-on-the-raspberry-pi-in-5-simple-steps-3mgl) toutorial

Comment: Thanks, it worked form me! Also @fepegar told that the installation can be not OK. How I would repair it?

Comment: Worked for me on the wsl2 running Ubuntu too.

Comment: Thanks! This gave me a lot more info and the actual error of why docker wasn't starting: `failed to start daemon: Error initializing network controller: error obtaining controller instance: unable to add return rule in DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 chain`, which I was able to solve by switching [iptables to nftables in my Debian](https://forums.docker.com/t/failing-to-start-dockerd-failed-to-create-nat-chain-docker/78269/2).

Comment: it also helped me in wsl2

Comment: This works. Neither `sudo service docker start` nor `sudo service docker start` worked.
but if you had previously run docker, first I had to stop docker using `sudo service docker stop` before running `sudo dockerd`

Comment: `dockerd` gives
`bash: dockerd: command not found`, and `sudo apt-get install dockerd` shows `E: Unable to locate package dockerd`

Comment: @JohnJiang which operating system you're using?

Comment: @YashPokar I am using ubuntu 18.04

Comment: @JohnJiang could you try re-installing docker and then run

Comment: After this :sudo dockerd
"INFO[2023-04-09T17:54:27.719475449+06:00] Starting up                                  
failed to start daemon: pid file found, ensure docker is not running or delete /var/run/docker.pid"

Comment: it is working for my Linux enviroment within Windows(wsl2) Thanks

Comment: sudo: dockerd: command not found

Answer (score 128):

I just hit this after doing a fresh install of DOCKER from the main docs.
The problem for me was that immediately after the install, the service is not running.

These commands will help you to make sure docker is up and running for your run command to find it:

```
$ sudo service --status-all 
$ sudo service docker start
```

Comment: I don't think a second sudo service docker start is necessary. First 2 lines were enough for me. Can you edit your answer?

Comment: this has worked for me. in wsl2

Answer (score 82):

Easy way to fix this issue, try this

```
sudo su
systemctl start docker
systemctl enable docker
systemctl restart docker
```

or

```
sudo systemctl start docker
sudo systemctl enable docker
sudo systemctl restart docker
```

Comment: systemctl restart docker

Comment: don't forget to do it with god rights, aka 'root' user: sudo su

Comment: You don't need to both `start` and `restart`. Just `enable` and `restart` then.

Answer (score 80):

You can get this error if docker doesn't shut down cleanly. The following answer is for the docker snap package.

Run `snap logs docker` and look for the following:

```
Error starting daemon: pid file found, ensure docker is not running or delete /var/snap/docker/179/run/docker.pid
```

Deleting that file and restarting docker worked for me.

```
rm /var/snap/docker/<your-version-number>/run/docker.pid
snap stop docker
snap start docker
```

Make sure to replace ‍‍‍‍`<your-version-number>‍` with the appropriate version number.

Comment: How can I prevent this from happening? Every time I turn on my PC, I have to remove docker.pid!

Answer (score 61):

Ubuntu 22.04 is my operating system. After conducting extensive research and browsing numerous websites, I discovered that running Docker as a non-root user creates a different context. My problem was resolved by using the commands listed below.

```
docker context ls
```

```
docker context use default
```

Comment: This was what did it for me on Pop OS 22.04.

Comment: this is the only solution worked for me, 2023, ubuntu20

Comment: Hours. Hours and hours and hours, before I stumbled on this answer. Thank you, sincerely.

Pop OS 22.04 here as well, March 2023. THIS was the answer. I'd somehow created and locked docker into a different "context" in my home folder. (Re)setting it to default fixed it.

Thank you thank you thank you

Comment: works on fedora too

Comment: I also use ubuntu 22.04, after days and days of research, this is the only one that worked for me. i wished i could double vote this. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Worked for me on openSUSE Tumbleweed with Docker version 24.0.4-ce, build 4ffc61430bbe

Comment: You saved my day. Thank you man

Comment: Wow... you totally saved me. Linux Mint user, I'm quite speechless that docker DOES NOT mention this as a potential problem that may happen. Thank you so much!

Comment: Works on Arch btw

Comment: Under a Mac this is the only thing that works.

Comment: Oh thank god, kudos, worked for me ubuntu23

Answer (score 57):

[image]

I just simply forget running the Docker Desktop in my mac, after running Docker Desktop, you will be good to go.

Comment: It worked for me as well I forgot to run the Docker Desktop on my mac. Thank you

Comment: This worked for me as a mac m1 user. But I am curious why did it start working after opening docker desktop ? Is there some pre-defined configuration which enables/starts docker engine running ?

Comment: I believe there is demon process init when the docker desk running

Comment: After about 20 mins of trying to figure out what was wrong, turns out I just forgot to start Docker Desktop. This helped a lot, thank you.

Comment: Note that OP was asking about Linux, not Mac. The path mentioned in the question was never used on a Mac...

Comment: @AlexisWilke the error message on mac is nearly the same,  it does say "Unix" on it and this solution fixes it. IIRC it said `ERROR: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at //Unix/<some user path>/.docker/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?`

Answer (score 45):

First, try with `sudo`, as the current user may not have access permissions to communicate to docker daemon i.e.:

`/var/run/docker.sock`

If its still not working, then, after the installation, simply stop the docker daemon:

```
sudo service docker stop
```

And, run the following command to start the daemon in background:

```
sudo nohup docker daemon -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375 -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock
```

To make working with Docker easier, you should add your username to
the Docker users group. Adding a user to the group can be done with the
command below:

```
sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
```

Also, this step is mentioned in the [official documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/linux-postinstall) of docker Post-installation steps for Linux.

**Ubuntu 16.04** users can follow these steps:

Inside file `/lib/systemd/system/docker.service` change:

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd fd://
```

to

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375
```

Inside file `/etc/init.d/docker` change:

```
DOCKER_OPTS=
```

to

```
DOCKER_OPTS="-H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375"
```

and then restart your machine, and start playing with docker.

Comment: running `sudo nohup docker daemon -H http://tcp://0.0.0.0:2375 () -H http://unix:///var/run/docker.sock` gives `bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('`

Comment: I am running redhat linux

Comment: ohh... sorry. Extra chars (),  updated.  Which version of RHEL ? Simply check what value you get with $DOCKER_HOST ?

Comment: $ sudo systemctl enable docker  to start the docker service at boot time.

Comment: I am now trying to install Docker on  `CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611 (Core)` ... But now error is `Your Linux kernel version 2.6.32-042stab116.2 is not supported for running docker. Please upgrade your kernel to 3.10.0 or newer.` ... can i update the kernel using `yum update kernel` ... ???? question is, will it delete everything on my server? its a live servers with a website running on it, i dont want to mess it up.

Comment: Yes. It's true you require min kernel version 3.10.0 or newer... Yes, be careful, if it's container environment, you could lose everything... as the kernel is shared b/w the containers. But, if it's VM env you could possibly do it with some techniques... like migrating your production server.. etc.

Comment: Warning to anyone following this advice, `-H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375` exposes an unencrypted root login over the network without any password.

Comment: I saw docker not starting because of not enough space.

Answer (score 34):

This usually happened if you haven't stopped docker probably.

To resolve

```
service docker stop
cd /var/run/docker/libcontainerd
rm -rf containerd/*
rm -f docker-containerd.pid
service docker start
```

then "docker run...." to download your image and start the container as usual

Answer (score 27):

It's worked for me:

```
sudo systemctl unmask docker
sudo systemctl start docker
```

Comment: what does it do?

Comment: @DJ_Stuffy_K Masking a service prevents the service from being started manually or automatically, which is a stronger version of disable. Masking disables all symlinks of the specified unit file are removed. [For more details](https://adeshsuryan.in/what-is-docker-mask-and-how-to-unmask-docker-service/)

Answer (score 23):

This works fine for me..!

```
service docker restart
```

Comment: For some reason, even though I ran this command earlier (and it didn't work at that time), for some reason something *else* I did while going through the answers on this list led to this command suddenly working for me. Here is subset of the commands I ran in-between the failing and working invocations of `service docker restart`: `service docker stop`, `service docker start`, `docker context use default`, `systemctl stop docker`, `systemctl stop docker.socket`.  *One* or more of those may have caused a subsequence `service docker restart` to work, and `docker run hello-world` succeeded.

Answer (score 19):

I had this problem after closing docker while pulling a container:

```
docker pull mongo
```

At first I was getting weird errors so I purged docker:

```
sudo apt-get purge docker.io
```

and reinstalled:

```
sudo apt-get install docker.io
```

All of this did nothing; I couldn't even run the "hello-world" container.

**The correct fix, for me at least was:**

```sh
systemctl unmask docker.service
systemctl unmask docker.socket
systemctl start docker.service
```

After this I could pull mongo and run "hello world".

Comment: I had to do it with Sudo on a Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Thank you for that. Glad to be able to find such a simple fix

Comment: The only option that helped me on Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 19):

I guess if you are using WSL with GUI, then you could just try

```
sudo /etc/init.d/docker start
```

Comment: It is true for WSL on windows 10.

Comment: top. worked for me. thanks.;

Answer (score 17):

On Ubuntu 22  "**sudo service docker start**" worked for me.

```
vikaspiprade@AUMEL-P7750-VP:~$ sudo docker run hello-world
docker: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at 
unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?.
See 'docker run --help'.
vikaspiprade@AUMEL-P7750-VP:~$ sudo /var/run/docker.sock
sudo: /var/run/docker.sock: command not found
vikaspiprade@AUMEL-P7750-VP:~$ /var/run/docker.sock
-bash: /var/run/docker.sock: Permission denied
vikaspiprade@AUMEL-P7750-VP:~$ sudo service docker stop
* Docker already stopped - file /var/run/docker-ssd.pid not found.
vikaspiprade@AUMEL-P7750-VP:~$ sudo service docker start
* Starting Docker: docker                                                                                       
[ OK ]
vikaspiprade@AUMEL-P7750-VP:~$
```

[image]

Answer (score 13):

if you are using MAC so just type docker in finder it will automatically resolve.

Answer (score 11):

On Ubuntu 20.04 and Docker version 20.10.11,as a non root user, Running:

```
sudo service docker start
```

Then checking the status

```
sudo service docker status
```

Shows

```
* Docker is running
```

But trying any docker command such as

```
docker images
```

Shows the same error

```
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

Running the below solves it

```
sudo service docker restart
```

Restart solved it, while start did not

Comment: I have no idea why this works, but it worked for me on WSL.

Answer (score 9):

I'm running on root and tried below, it worked:

```
service docker start

export DOCKER_HOST="tcp://0.0.0.0:2375"
```

Comment: If this works on your host, then you effectively have no root password. Anyone with access to that port can run commands as root on your host.

Answer (score 8):

## 2022 Solution

This work by my side:

Add the below in your volume:

```
volumes:
 - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
```

after that execute the below command

```
 sudo  chown 1000:1000 /var/run/docker.sock
```

Please note 1000 is the ID of the user. to know it execute the below command:

```
id
```

Or, if $USER contains your user's name:

```
 sudo  chown $USER:$USER /var/run/docker.sock
```

Comment: It worked for me without needing to add the volumes

Comment: hello, i am new to the docker and tried to run docker run hello-world and encountered with this problem. Can you please tell me where i find the volume and add those? Thank you

Answer (score 7):

here's the solution which works for me on Linux

`systemctl start docker`.

Comment: For Ubuntu WSL on windows use - `sudo service docker start`

Comment: "Failed to start docker..service: Unit docker..service not found."

Answer (score 7):

I also received the error message below, after installing the docker and running: docker run hello-world
#Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix: /var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?

Here's a solution, what worked for me.
Environment

- Windows 10 (Don't forget to enable on windows: Settings> Update and Security> Developer mode)
- Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
- Docker Desktop version 2.3.0.2 (45183)

  - Enable in Docker Desktop: Expose daemon on tcp: // localhost: 2375 without TLS
  - Docker Desktop must also be running (connected to Docker Hub ... just log in)

## After installing ubuntu, update the repository

```
sudo apt-get update
```

## To use a repository over HTTPS

```
sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl gnupg-agent software-properties-common
```

## Add the official Docker GPG key:

```
curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo apt-key add -
```

## Make sure you now have the key with the fingerprint

```
sudo apt-key fingerprint 0EBFCD88
```

## Update the repository

```
sudo apt-get update
```

## Update the docker repository

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb [arch = amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu $ (lsb_release -cs) stable "
```

## Update the repository again

```
sudo apt-get update
```

## Command to install the docker in version: 5: 18.09.9 ~ 3-0 ~ ubuntu-bionic

```
sudo apt-get install docker-ce = 5: 18.09.9 ~ 3-0 ~ ubuntu-bionic docker-ce-cli = 5: 18.09.9 ~ 3-0 ~ ubuntu-bionic containerd.io
```

## Command to set the DOCKER_HOST

```
export DOCKER_HOST="tcp://0.0.0.0:2375"
```

Note: put the command above in your profile to start with the ubunto
ex: echo "export DOCKER_HOST="tcp://0.0.0.0:2375"" >> ~/.bashrc

## Add user to the docker group

```
sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
```

## Restart ubuntu

(Close and open the ubuntu window again)
or run:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

## Testing the installation (DO NOT use more sudo before docker commands (it will give an error), the user "root" has already been included in the docker group)

```
docker run hello-world
```

## The message below should be displayed

Hello from Docker!
This message shows that your installation appears to be working correctly.

Note: if it fails, run the command again:

```
export DOCKER_HOST="tcp://0.0.0.0:2375"
```

Reference: https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/
Session: INSTALL DOCKER ENGINE

#For other versions of the docker that can be installed with ubuntu, see the repository using the command below:
apt-cache madison docker-ce

## Then install the desired version of the docker:

```
sudo apt-get install docker-ce = <VERSION_STRING> docker-ce-cli = <VERSION_STRING> containerd.io
```

Comment: Hi @ukaliko, did you install "Docker Desktop" on windows?  this instruction : https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/#installation-methods  does not mention the "docker desktop"

Comment: Hi @ukaliko, I decided to install the "docker desktop" on windows. and now all works. maybe in the future i will try to upgrade WSL to WSL2 and see if i can avoid the unsafe tcp 2375 port thing.

Comment: just a small comment @ukaliko, ```sudo usermod -aG docker $ USER```, you had a space between ```$``` and ```USER```

Comment: Thanks for letting me know soMuchToLearnAndShare , here's the tip guys. soMuchToLearnAndShare sorry I just saw your comment. But I'm glad that everything worked! Show!...Vlw soMuchToLearnAndShare. Strong hug!

Answer (score 7):

It happens by the docker is not started yet.

Please check the docker status

`$ sudo systemctl status docker`

Then start and enable the docker and recheck the status

```
$ sudo systemctl start docker && sudo systemctl enable docker && sudo systemctl status docker
```

Thats it. Now the last step for checking the docker is working fine

```
$ sudo docker run hello-world
```

Answer (score 6):

for linux run

`sudo dockerd`

However, if you use Docker Client for mac it won't work. try the below code

`$socat TCP-LISTEN:2376,reuseaddr,fork UNIX-CLIENT:/var/run/docker.sock`

https://forums.docker.com/t/using-pycharm-docker-plugin-with-docker-beta/8617/9

That workaround opens port 2376 to the world... as TLS isn't enabled, this is a bad idea as anyone on the same network can hijack your docker daemon

Comment: the solution is awesome

Comment: upvote please :)

Answer (score 6):

Sometimes, for some reason, Docker turns off my ubuntu integration, and I get this same `Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?` error.

Go into your docker desktop settings cog at top right of the window > Resources > WSL Integration and turn the integration back on:

[image]

Comment: New Update for version `Docker Desktop 4.24.2 (124339)` 
go to

`Advanced -> Allow the default Docker socket to be used (requires password)`

Comment: I had this occur on multiple computers recently.

Answer (score 5):

It could be related to no disk space left on the hard drive. Make sure you have space left on the device, Docker can't start up if there isn't any space left.

Answer (score 5):

I had this problem when docker was started after my terminal was started. Restarting the terminal or the process hosting the terminal (such as vscode) resolved the issue.

Answer (score 5):

In WSL, running `dockerd` solve the issue.

```
$ sudo dockerd
```

Answer (score 4):

I was trying to run docker(just installed) in an instance of AWS when the message appears.
I just write `sudo service docker start` and works fine for me.

Also see [AWS with Docker](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/docker-basics.html)

Answer (score 4):

Make sure information in this path `/etc/docker/daemon.json`

```
{
  "registry-mirror": [
    "https://registry.docker-cn.com"
  ],
  "insecure-registries": [
    "192.168.199.100:5000"
  ]
}
```

delete

```
"insecure-registries": [
    "192.168.199.100:5000"
]
```

and runs well
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CC1gR.png)

Comment: great answer! THANKS!

Comment: also make sure the content in the .json file is a valid JSON :-) (you may forget to put `{}` around partial config, `,`comma at the end etc...

Comment: A very obscure cause - invalid daemon.json!   You can spot this by doing `sudo journalctl -u docker.service` and then `G` (to go to end).   You'll see entries like`Jul 23 16:38:14 someSystemName dockerd[2192]: time="2023-07-23T16:38:14.306020907-04:00" level=error msg="Error writing log message" driver=json-file error="error writing log entry: write /var/lib/docker/containers/39571f0b7e97a496a5b24ddd`      One possible cause for this is when you paste a daemon.json from a web site or word doc and the character formatting is not quite right.    Just retype everything to make sure you're good.

Answer (score 4):

I installed docker from snap repository. So I also had to start from snap (running Ubuntu).

`sudo snap start docker`

Otherwise you can also install it from their [repositories](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/#install-using-the-repository).

Comment: The only thing that worked for me!!! Thanks

Answer (score 4):

This works in my case:

```
sudo service docker start
```

Answer (score 4):

[image: docker desktop settings]

- If you're using **MacOS**
- Open the **docker desktop app**
- Go over to **setting -> advanced**.
- There you should see a checkbox with the option to **Allow the
  default Docker socket to be used**.

It was unchecked by default so turning that on is what worked for me.

Comment: worked for me! this answer should be marked as a solution.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem for gitlab CI running node:lts image:

- I just restarted the docker daemon and restart the container, it worked for me.

Comment: Restarting the docker desktop worked for me.Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This exception comes when the service of docker is not running or the logged in user dont have the permission to access docker and generally it comes in RedHat

Using below command should resolve the issue

> > > sudo service docker start

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In root mode, run the command `systemctl start docker`

And afterwards, you can check the status by running `systemctl status docker`

Answer (score 2):

use this in ubuntu 
export DOCKER_HOST=tcp://localhost:2375

Comment: If this works on your system, then you effectively have no root password. Anyone with access to that port can run commands as root on the host.

Answer (score 2):

export DOCKER_HOST=tcp://localhost:2375 is perfect for anyone who doesn't have sudo access and the user doesn't have access to unix:///var/run/docker.sock

Comment: This is also useful for anyone that doesn't normally have root access but would like to easily become root on your host. Anyone with access to that port can run commands as root.

Comment: @BMitch care to elaborate?

Comment: @FranMarzoa from another user that you do not trust, or even another host, you can run any `docker run` command with the root user inside the container, privileged, with host namespaces on pid and network, and mounting the root filesystem ok the box.

Answer (score 2):

None of the current answers worked for my version of this error. I'm using the desktop version of Ubuntu 18. The following two commands fixed the issue.

`sudo snap connect docker:home :home`

`sudo snap start docker`

Answer (score 2):

This might be a bit late for you but hope it will help someone find their way through the docker jungles.
The problem might be coming from a tcp port binding issue
verify if this file exists

> /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d

this is the default UNIX socket listening override file. The file might actauly be empty, but i find that the fact that it exists sometimes causes some headaches like what you faced.
if it exists 1. then 2. if not just go straight to 2.

```
1. $ sudo rm -rf /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d

2. $ sudo systemctl deamon-reload
```

I find that some of the recommendations here overlook the error being in the actual daemon failing to load

A good friend when playing with docker is

```
$ systemctl status docker.service
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to install docker with wsl 2 linux subsystem in windows, please read [this](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/wsl/) document and check whether this command is executed:

```
wsl.exe --set-version (distro name) 2
```

and also check in your Windows OS `docker->settings->Resources->Enable integration` with additional distros: are checked on and restarted.

Answer (score 2):

To me docker was really not running missing the following command to start it:

```
systemctl --user start docker-desktop
```

Answer (score 2):

As a **Mac M1** user who is prohibited from using the Docker Desktop on the work computer, I had to use `podman` (the Docker alternative) in the console.
It has very similar commands and does its job.

This is where I've found the solution: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/672202

Answer (score 1):

I faced same issue on Linux when I installed docker using yum (yum install docker).

Resolution: download docker binary from official site: [docker install](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/binaries/), unpack and follow the installation steps.

Answer (score 1):

For those fresh installing & trying to running docker on RaspberryPi (RPi) like me, **I needed to reboot my RPi** 4B+ to resolve this issue and actually run the docker daemon.

By the time of writing this contribution [this great manual](https://dev.to/elalemanyo/how-to-install-docker-and-docker-compose-on-raspberry-pi-1mo) does mention the necessity to reboot RPi, but only after setting "Non root-user to the Docker Group".

HTH, should someone miss this like me..

Answer (score 1):

I read through all the answers and didn't find anything close to my situation. In the end, the problem turned out to be that `docker` was installed twice on my system, once on `snap`, and another time through the convenience script. So, if anybody runs into this problem, make sure to check that `docker` isn't installed in multiple places because that can cause some really weird behavior.

Comment: Make sure to come back tomorrow and mark this as your answer!

Comment: Interesting... I do have it installed twice, I installed Docker manually in ubuntu and I can get it to work through the terminal, whereas in VSC the docker tools never freaking work

Answer (score 1):

for me the cause of the error was docker desktop i had forced quit it .
so restarting  docker desktop worked for me  and error got resolved .

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as code segment, commands or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

on windows 11 with ubuntu 22 the command `wsl.exe --update`
in power shell helped me to run docker through containerd as it was on windows 10

before that i was getting `Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:/var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running` which wasn't happend to me on windows 10 ubuntu 20.04 with the same set up.

starting with ordinary `sudo service docker start`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error with Rancher Desktop (v1.8.1) on MacOS with Intel Silicon. This issue happened right after installation. I did not change anything compared to the basic settings.

Turns out one needs to select dockerd as container engine instead of the default containerd in order to use docker from cli.

[image: Settings in Rancher Desktop]

I hope this helps somebody.

Answer (score 1):

I tried all the previous solutions and couldn't resolve my problem. Commands like `systemctl` and `service` were unknown to the command line.

That is when I thought about **actually opening docker application, and get the whale icon on my menubar shown in my laptop**. When I did, all the commands started working, and the error was gone too.

I just wanted to add this INCASE someone needs to see the obvious.

Answer (score 1):

If you download the Docker app, setup everything including your profile, and then keep it running while executing the command, it should work.

Answer (score 1):

As this question thread become more like knowledge database over the time and different distributives, I'll add info what helped me for `20.04.6 LTS (Focal Fossa)`. Maybe others will find it helpful for them and their investigation path in other cases too:

I had some sort of mix on my machine (aml compute instance) from the beginning, so it was good to cleanup first and go for moby-related containers tool (which is popular atm):

To re-install it (remove snap version and get moby engine):

```
sudo snap remove docker
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install moby-engine -f
sudo apt-get install moby-runc
sudo apt-get install moby-containerd
sudo apt-get install moby-engine
```

To add docker compose (if you need one): `sudo apt-get install docker-compose-plugin`

To check/start the service:

```
sudo service --status-all # checks status of all services, find docker here
sudo dockerd # just to check it works or no and see logs immediately
sudo service docker restart # to start/restart the service
```

for some cases when it says errors about `daemon.json`:

```
sudo mv /etc/docker/daemon.json /etc/docker/daemon_old.json
```

Start your container with docker compose plugin (make sure you have required dockerfile/docker-compose files):

```
docker compose up --build
```

Good luck and have fun!

Answer (score 1):

For Debian, The docker installer uses iptables for nat. Unfortunately Debian uses nftables. You can convert the entries over to nftables or just setup Debian to use the legacy iptables.

```
sudo update-alternatives --set iptables /usr/sbin/iptables-legacy

sudo update-alternatives --set ip6tables /usr/sbin/ip6tables-legacy
```

dockerd, should start fine after switching to iptables-legacy.

```
sudo service docker start
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, It might just work for you if you are using Ubuntu 16 or 18 (14 may also work). Easy to give a try:

Go to Ubuntu Software, type in Docker.
Uninstall docker (108 mb) if it is preinstalled there.
Install docker
Now run the commands and see if the same error comes

The error:

[image]

After doing the above steps.
[image]

As you can see, it worked:)

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution was to simply make sure I had installed the correct Docker package. For example, for Ubuntu the [depreciated packages](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/) are:

- docker
- docker-engine
- docker.io
- containerd
- runc

For installation check https://docs.docker.com. Instructions are provided for [Ubuntu](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/), [CentOS](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/centos/), [Debian](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/debian/) and [Fedora](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/fedora/) at the time of writing.

Comment: You missed some steps: follow this link for signing the repo. https://medium.com/@sebagomez/installing-the-docker-client-on-ubuntus-windows-subsystem-for-linux-612b392a44c4

Comment: @Robert, above I also refer to the official docs.docker to get the PGP key. This is more secure than users copying it from this site or medium.

Comment: I tried the ubuntu steps and those are not working. Need the signing process and the link I provided.

Comment: @Robert, thanks I have removed my incomplete instructions and instead just refer to the official documentation.

Answer (score 0):

For everyone who is having problems with Docker at the time of installation.

An error pointing to a failure in the docker service, do the commands below.

```
$ sudo apt update

$ sudo apt install apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl gnupg2 software-properties-common

$ curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/debian/gpg | sudo apt-key add -

$ sudo add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/debian $(lsb_release -cs) stable"

$ sudo apt update

$ apt-cache policy docker-ce

$ sudo apt install docker-ce
```

Answer (score 0):

Just adding to the knowledge base. I found this [video](https://nickjanetakis.com/blog/a-linux-dev-environment-on-windows-with-wsl-2-docker-desktop-and-more) helpful. I do not have `DOCKER_HOST` defined. I do have a `/etc/wsl.conf` that has:

```
[automount]
root = /
options = "metadata"
```

After Restarting a few times docker hello-world worked.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see this solution mentioned, so I'll post it in case it might help someone. I was running into this error on my MacOS machine. The reason was that I had the `DOCKER_HOST` environment variable set in my dotfiles. Unsetting it through `unset DOCKER_HOST` did the trick. I found the tip in the official docker for Mac documentation: https://docs.docker.com/desktop/mac/troubleshoot/#workarounds-for-common-problems.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error message when I was not logged into Docker.  Before more advanced troubleshooting, make sure you're logged into Docker.  On mac, open the Docker Desktop app and sign in.  This fixed the error for me.

Answer (score 0):

**Docker.sock works as a channel to communicate between docker CLI and docker daemon. You can simply run your container by using this command.**

```
docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock  <ImageName>:latest
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case when doing `sudo dockerd --debug` it showed this error: "`failed to start daemon: Error initializing network controller: error obtaining controller instance: failed to create NAT chain DOCKER: Iptables not found`"

To solve it I put:

```
sudo update-alternatives --set iptables /usr/sbin/iptables-legacy
sudo update-alternatives --set ip6tables /usr/sbin/ip6tables-legacy
sudo systemctl start docker.service
```

For more details you can check: https://forums.docker.com/t/failing-to-start-dockerd-failed-to-create-nat-chain-docker/78269

Answer (score 0):

## Assign Ownership to the Docker Unix Socket

The “cannot connect to the Docker daemon” error also happens if the Unix socket file for Docker doesn’t have the correct ownership assigned.

### 1. Check ownership for the Docker Unix socket:

```
sudo ls -la /var/run/docker.sock
```

[image]

### 2. If necessary, grant the user ownership with:

```
sudo chown [username]:docker /var/run/docker.sock
```

Credits to [Phonenixnap](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/cannot-connect-to-the-docker-daemon-error) For answer

Answer (score 0):

I just got the same error the docker commands did not work after installing docker desktop for macos even though it shows running, so the fix for it is i restarted my laptop and docker commands started working now and the pull commands and ps commands doesnot give error now.

FIX IS: Restart your laptop...

[image]

Comment: This fixed the problem I was having on MacOS--thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If have a Jenkins setup of Kubernetes cluster and I was facing the same issue while trying to build Dockerfiles using the Jenkins agent(pod gets launched in K8s cluster).

Steps to fix:

1. Install Jenkins using the cmd:

> ```
> helm repo add jenkinsci https://charts.jenkins.io/
> ```

```
helm upgrade --install my-jenkins jenkinsci/jenkins --set rbac.create=true --set agent.privileged=true --set serviceAccount.create=false  --set agent.runAsUser=0
```

2. Install and configure ***`docker`*** plugin.
3. create a Jenkins job and use the pipeline script mentioned below to install docker in the agent for building Dockerfile.

   pipeline {

   ```
   agent any

   stages {
       stage('Installing Dependencies'){
           steps {
               sh "apt-get update"
               sh "apt-get install build-essential python3 -y"
               sh "apt-get install unzip"
               sh "apt-get install ca-certificates"
               sh "apt-get install gnupg -y"
               sh "apt-get install lsb-release -y"
               sh "apt install curl"
               sh "curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/debian/gpg | gpg --dearmor -o /usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.gpg"
               sh 'echo "deb [arch=$(dpkg --print-architecture) signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.gpg] https://download.docker.com/linux/debian $(lsb_release -cs) stable" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list > /dev/null'
               sh "apt update"
               sh "apt -y install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io "
               sh 'usermod -aG docker "$(whoami)"'
               sh "service docker start"
               sh "sleep 10"
               sh "docker ps"
               sh "docker images"
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   }

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this for latest solution,

sudo ln -s ~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/docker.raw.sock /var/run/docker.sock
DOCKER_HOST=unix:///var/run/docker.sock docker ps # test that it works using linked socket file

Answer (score 0):

I had been facing a similar problem. Following is the solution worked for me.
Check for virtual machine permissions in the bios menu of the device. Enable it if disabled, then try to run docker it will work now.

Answer (score -1):

This issue can be resolved permanently by running 
1. systemctl enable docker
2. service docker start

Comment: Seems like I need to start docker service by `service start docker` everytime I reboot the computer.

Comment: @PranKumarSarkar Not if you run "sudo systemctl enable docker"

Answer (score -1):

Use
`docker start <your_container_name>`

Then connect to database by using 
`mssql -u <yourUsername> -p <yourPassword>`

If you get an error in the first step then the docker is running and go with the second step.

Note: I use Mac as my primary OS and this might be the same answer for Unix based OSs. If not! Sorry in advance.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue. In my case, VPN was the culprit. Turning off the VPN helped with the successful installation.

Answer (score -2):

Just restarting the system worked for me. It might be a temporary issue

Comment: I found I was actually in a shell inside the docker image!  Just open another terminal and type `docker ps` to see what images are running.

Comment: This was useful for me  

I had updated Docker and some terms and conditions was changed 

At loggin, Docker was relaunched and request me permissions with my password and accept the new terms and conditions