# I get an error that I can not connect to the macos :: daemon daemon

Tags: docker

I am using a docker in a mac mojave.

I normally use the docker, but suddenly I get an error today.

I downloaded the docker from the official homepage of the docker rather than the brew, but when I input the docker command, the following error

**error**

> Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is
>   the docker daemon running?.

**Dozer version**

> 18.06.1-ce, build e68fc7a

I looked at the article asking me to install docker-machine and virtualbox to solve my problem.

However, I have not had any problems using the Docker until now, but I am now wondering about this error.

Of course, I have been using the docker for a few days and have been doing tutorials such as simply loading images.

Comment: "Is the docker daemon running" - well is it running or not?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:/var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44678725/cannot-connect-to-the-docker-daemon-at-unix-var-run-docker-sock-is-the-docker)

Comment: I tried to check if the daemon is running, but the service command does not work.

Comment: I removed ~ / Library / Containers / com.docker. * And solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Docker cannot run on MAC directly , you need to install and configure Docker For MAC , that uses a form of virtualization.

https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/install/

Comment: I removed ~ / Library / Containers / com.docker. * And solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error after using the downloaded mac installer. It went away after I opened the docker app for the first time and accepted the terms. I noticed opening docker created some files, so I suppose it's setting up some stuff when you open it for the first time.