# Why am I getting a "Cannot connect to the Docker daemon" error in WSL2?

Tags: docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux, docker-desktop, wsl-2, docker-daemon

Here is my setup:

- `Windows 10 PRO - build 19041.153` - insider program - slow ring
- `Ubuntu 18.04LTS` subsystem in WSL2 mode
- `Docker for desktop 2.2.0.4` - enabled WSL2 integration with my Ubuntu subsystem

I am currently forced to use Windows for development, so I became a
Microsoft insider member and installed ubuntu with WSL2 mode. Docker desktop supports integration for WSL2, so I tried it...

For a week it worked flawlessly. Today after a PC restart, I can't get docker running again. Ubuntu can see the injected binaries from Docker desktop, but it can't connect to windows hosted docker daemon anymore.

When I call in the WSL terminal `docker info` it returns

```
$ docker info
Client:
 Debug Mode: false

Server:
ERROR: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
errors pretty printing info
```

or with `docker-compose up`

```
ERROR: Couldn't connect to Docker daemon at http+docker://localhost - is it running?

If it's at a non-standard location, specify the URL with the DOCKER_HOST environment variable.
```

What I've tried already:

- expose daemon without TLS with envs like `DOCKER_HOST=localhost:2375`, `DOCKER_HOST=tcp://localhost:2375`, `DOCKER_HOST=127.0.0.1:2375`, `DOCKER_HOST=tcp://127.0.0.1:2375` => same result
- uninstall Docker desktop and install previous version
- turn off windows firewall

I really, really need this to work. Thanks for any ideas. Weirdest thing is it worked yesterday and I didn't make any changes in system from then...

Comment: Installed another Ubuntu (16.04) and it works. Well thats cool, but how to fix my main subsys. :)

Comment: Did you try `unset DOCKER_HOST`? Sounds weird, but that's what did it for me.

Comment: @Josiah that did it for me!

Comment: @Josiah thanks did it for me too!

Comment: unset DOCKER_HOST and restart docker desktop worked for me.

Comment: maybe it helps someone: Check that you distro runs in correct version `wsl -l -v`. I accidentally changed the wsl version from 2 to 1 a long time before and did not remember it anymore.... if its the same for you `wsl --set-version (distro name) 2` and afterwards restart docker-desktop will fix fix it.

Comment: unset DOCKER_HOST also worked for me !

Comment: Enabling WSL Integration and setting the distro install as default should be all you need. https://stackoverflow.com/a/71297271/401173

Answer (score 74):

I know this may be outdated for the present question, but this should save us precious time, especially when Windows 20H1=2004 is going to Production this month (May 2020).

**Operating System Version**: Windows 10 Education (Same as Enterprise and a superset of Pro).
  **Version**: 2004
  **Build (Version OS)**: 19041.264
  **Others**: Windows Feature Experience Pack 120.2202.130.0.
  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  **Shell**: WSL Terminal

**First**, I have installed *WSL v1* previously, then executed the procedure to upgrade to *WSLv2*, and this error shows up: "ERROR: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at tcp://localhost:2375. Is the docker daemon running?".

**Second**, to fix that error, I followed instructions stated here: [Link](https://codesthq.com/painless-way-to-wsl-2-with-docker/), and it worked.

**Third**, after some tests I think the missing change in the upgrade, was removing the `DOCKER_HOST` variable from shell's start script.

**SUMMARY:** In my case, the procedure for a permanent fix should be the following **STEPs**:

**1.** Test if it's your case unsetting `DOCKER_HOST` variable (See image below).

**2.** If the error disappears with previous step, then time to fix changes by removing the setting of the `DOCKER_HOST` variable in the shell's start script (In my case was `*$HOME/.bashrc*`).
  Commented this out:
  `#export DOCKER_HOST=tcp://localhost:2375`
  `#export DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1`

*NOTE*: Also include `DOCKER_BUILDKIT`.

**3.** Close and open the Terminal.

Test in **Step 1**:
[image]


***Good luck!!***

Comment: For me it worked after unsetting the old variable (removed from .bashrc). Thanks!

Comment: My question is why the heck wasn't this clearly documented by Docker in the first place!

Comment: Thanks @Patricio your solution worked for me. 
My mistake was that I installed `docker-compose` inside WSL when Docker Desktop is already managing all that!

Comment: Following the instructions in the linked article worked for me. I had no `DOCKER_HOST` environment variable so I needed to follow the full instructions and install Docker Desktop Edge and it works great.

Comment: For me the key was uninstalling docker-ce and docker-ce-cli which was still present as i was using WSL v1 before. Best hint from the linked ressource: *"Some of the available tutorials or advices can be confusing because this time you shouldn't install or configure anything related to Docker under your WSL Linux distribution."*

Answer (score 70):

If it helps anyone else that is having this issue, for me it turned out that my subsystem was suddenly (and "on its own") ticked off in docker's RESOURCES > WSL INTEGRATION settings.

Comment: This happened to me when upgrading from the Stable to Edge release.

Comment: Same for me. It happened when I added ubuntu 20 next to ubuntu 18

Comment: same here.. 

* ticked it on again
* run `wsl --shutdown`
* started WSL2 distro again
* still `docker ps` responds with `Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at...`

Was a restart required for you guys?

Comment: @spex66 i restarted and it still didn't work for me, did you have any luck?

Comment: Happened to me when I moved my VM's storage file through wsl commands, i.e. unregistering it and importing it again removes it from docker integration.

Comment: Sneaky untick after docker update. Wsl could connect again after manual tick :/

Comment: This is exactly what happened to me. I ticked the `Ubuntu` integration back, and after waiting ~30s it worked again. Thanks a lot dude!

Comment: Just happened to me as well in Docker Desktop 4.27.2

Comment: Yep just happened to me in 4.27.2

Answer (score 33):

On the Docker Desktop app I had to manually enable my distro integration under

```
Settings > Resources > WSL Integration
```

Comment: This solved it for me __more than once__! If you've done this before, check it again. I found the checkbox for "my default WSL distro" was checked, but the switch for "Ubuntu" under "additional distros" went off.

Answer (score 14):

I've tried soooo many things, and the stuff that worked for me, and no one ever mentioned to try:

(from Windows Powershell)

```
wsl --set-default <my-distro>
```

then and there, I could connect to docker without changing the `DOCKER_HOST` var.

Comment: This should be much higher in the results. This and enabling WSL Integration should be all you need.

Comment: This answer is easy and working.

Answer (score 13):

I had installed Docker for Windows, [as recommended](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/tutorials/wsl-containers), to use it with [WSL 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-manual#step-4---download-the-linux-kernel-update-package) and that does indeed start the docker daemon for you. But I don't need all the fancy features it offers so removed it and was pleased to see about 4GB freed and no extra icon in the system tray.

Now if I need to run docker commands I just begin with:

```
sudo dockerd &
```

This way I can have it running on the background on the same shell. Note that in this example I have setup `sudo` without password. If a password is required, I can do `sudo dockerd` and open another terminal tab.

Although this works as a quick temporary solution I've seen it cause [network issues](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/672321/212177) so I would not recommend it, and prefer using a [light VM instead](https://superuser.com/a/1681105/668905).

Answer (score 10):

1.open windows docker desktop --> Setting -->General --> Disable Expose daemon on tcp://localhost:2375 without TLS

[image: img1]

2.and then Go to Settings --> Resources --> WSL integration --> uncheck Enable integration with my default WSL distro and turn off integration with distro

[image: img2]

3.click apply and restart

4.then go to ubuntu
try  docker ps
`docker ps`
if it does not work, continue to run the following command
`unset DOCKER_HOST` to disable DOCKER_HOST

[image: img3]

Today I just tried it successfully

good luck to you

Comment: Worked for me with Windows 11 and Arch on WSL2.

Answer (score 4):

I have found my issue was due to mis-reading instructions., fixed on my windows version 1909 and WSL 2 with the following commands on CMD:

```
wsl.exe -l -v
wsl.exe --set-version ${distro-name} ${wsl version}
```

example:

```
C:\Users\xxxxx>wsl.exe -l -v
  NAME                   STATE           VERSION
* Ubuntu-18.04           Running         1
  docker-desktop-data    Running         2
  docker-desktop         Running         2

C:\Users\xxxxx>wsl.exe --set-version Ubuntu-18.04 2
Conversion in progress, this may take a few minutes...
For information on key differences with WSL 2 please visit https://aka.ms/wsl2
```

That's it

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me, but only after I updated my Windows with "Check for Updates", on `1909 Build 18363.1256` - works like a charm

Answer (score 3):

I found a 1.5 step fix.  Go here, uncheck `Enable`, then `Apply & restart` button.
Then check `Enable`, then `Apply & restart` button.

Docker now working fine in WSL2 Ubuntu.

[image]

Comment: Thank you!! this was the only thing that helped and I tried a billion things before this

Answer (score 2):

> ISSUE: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at tcp://127.0.0.1:2375

#### Powershell

```
wsl -l -v   # ALL DISPLAY "2"
```

#### Linux

```
unset DOCKER_HOST

/etc/init.d/docker restart
```

#### Restart Docker

```
windows docker restart
windows firewall off
```

#### Linux docker processes

```
docker ps
```

Comment: I get >'windows' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, the solution for me was to set my Ubuntu as the default wsl distribution: wsl --set-default Ubuntu

Comment: you are genuis, thanx

Answer (score 1):

After hours, my docker worked using following method.

1. Go to **docker desktop --> Setting -->General --> Disable Expose daemon on tcp://localhost:2375 without TLS**
2. Go to **Settings --> Resources --> WSL integration --> uncheck Enable integration with my default WSL distro and turn off integration with distro**
3. Restart Docker desktop
4. Now in WSL,

   ```
   unset DOCKER_HOST
   ```
5. Now try,

   ```
   docker ps
   ```

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is mostly correct. However, I wanted to specify that when using WSL2 + Docker Desktop:

- You must unset DOCKER_HOST which was previously needed in WSL1

  - Mine was defined in `~/.bashrc` in both Windows and WSL.
  - Delete in both. Also delete in Windows env variables via Control Panel.
  - Check with `env | grep -i docker` to make sure it's gone.
- You must also set the correct settings in Docker Desktop

  - Uncheck `Export daemon on tcp://localhost:2375 without TLS`
  - Check `Use the WSL2 based engine`
  - Resources -> WSL Integration -> Check `Enable integration with my default WSL distro`

Now, you can do a simple `docker info` to check if you're running the same server version in WSL and in Windows (Powershell).

Comment: As well as this answer:
`wsl -l` (in PowerShell) tells me `wsl default` is being reset to `docker-desktop-data (Default)`
I repeatedly have to flick the switch in Docker Desktop under Settings -> Resources -> WSL Integration to "Enable integration with additional distros:".
_or_
`wsl --set-default Ubuntu` in PowerShell

Comment: I say "repeatedly" because _I think_ these settings are lost when I restart Docker Desktop, or Windows.

Answer (score 0):

For whatever it's worth (this is an old thread). Maybe someone else is still desperately trying to solve this puzzle.

I have just stumbled over the solution in my case.
I am running the following

- docker desktop version 3.3.3
- wsl 2
- Fedora 33
  Over and over again I ran into this issue "Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock". Reinstalled, restarted, blablabla.

My ultimate error were access rights on /var/run/docker.sock, and I am running wsl under my personal user
srw-rw---- 1 root docker 0 May  7 10:29 /var/run/docker.sock

So if I run as root (sudo docker info) or I put myself into group "docker" (sudo usermod -aG docker $USER) I'm all well. Please look here https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/

Answer (score 0):

There is another very basic catch:

- **Ensure virtualization is enabled in the BIOS.**
- Please enable the Virtual Machine Platform Windows feature from the selection of additional Windows Features.
- **Now my motherboard is being very old, the BIOS does not support
  Enabling Virtualization.**
- Hence no solution will work for me.
- WSL Version 1 or 2 will come from Windows Update automatically.

Answer (score 0):

The following sequence worked for me:

1. Turn off all the WSL Integration checkboxes.
2. Apply & Restart
3. Turn back on either just the Default checkbox, or the specific distro slider, depending on whether it's the default or not.
4. Apply & Restart
5. Right-click the docker tray icon and **Restart Docker**.

It wasn't until step 5 that it actually started working.

I did have a container running at the time and "Apply & Restart" happened suspiciously fast, so I suspect it forgot to do the actual restarting part.

Answer (score 0):

Try launching the docker service inside wsl2:

```bash
sudo service docker start
```

Verify the server is running

```
docker info
```

Answer (score -1):

you can consider upgrading your version to 19582.1000 , it's work for me.

See [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4860).

[image]

Comment: Moved to build `19582.1001`. Same issue :(

Comment: you should upgrade to Docker Desktop WSL 2 backend
https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/wsl-tech-preview/

Comment: Did that. No luck. But it doesn't matter anymore. I deleted whole Ubuntu and started on clean slate and it's working. (for now). Thank you very much for reponses :)