# docker: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at tcp://0.0.0.0:2375. Is the docker daemon running?

Tags: bash, docker, ubuntu, docker-compose, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am stuck on this error since yesterday. I am trying to run the command
`docker run hello-world` on my Ubuntu bash but it keeps giving the same error. I don't understand what am I doing wrong.

[image]

My ~/.bashrc file also has the required environment variables.

[image]

[image]

Comment: If your `.bashrc` file is a PNG-format image like you've attached here, it won't work.  Can you [edit] your question to replace the screenshots of terminal windows with the plain-text content of these files instead?  You should not normally need to set `$DOCKER_HOST` at all, and if setting it to port 2375 works, it's a major security risk.

Comment: Agree with @DavidMaze on both counts.  First, recommend reading why we ask that you [not post text as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11810933).  Second, I think that it is the `DOCKER_HOST` that is *causing* the problem.  Try removing it - If it doesn't work, report the error new (as text!) in an edit to your question.  Thanks!

Comment: I'm just curious - As a user with reputation < 15, you should have received a warning message when posting those images that you should include the text - Is that feature not working currently, or did you just ignore it?  Want to make sure there's not a bug in the system.  Thanks!

Comment: Yes, the problem was with that DOCKER_HOST thing. And sorry about posting the screenshot instead of the text. I didn't know that. I removed that line and it works fine now. Thank you!

Comment: @Rogeorge Also another heads-up -- If you find the answer in another question (which you did, according to your answer), then you should flag your question as a "duplicate" of that other question.  Thanks! Re: [WSL2 Cannot connect to the Docker daemon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60708229/wsl2-cannot-connect-to-the-docker-daemon)

Answer (score -3):

have you tried to add docker group etc. ?
these are the required post installation steps:

```
sudo groupadd docker
sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
```

Log out and log back in so that your group membership is re-evaluated.

source: https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/

Comment: Those instructions are for Docker Engine.  This question is regarding Docker Desktop.  Docker Desktop automatically adds the `docker` group to a WSL instance and assigns the user to that group when the *"Enable integration with ..."* option is selected, which it is according to the screenshot above.  Thanks!

Comment: oops, have not noticed that ...