# everything going fine but still show Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock in docker

Tags: docker

I am using this command to list docker(18.09.6) process in CentOS 7.6:

```
docker ps
```

but it show this:

```
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running
```

I using this command to check my docker status:

```
[root@log001 run]# service docker status -l
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl status  -l docker.service
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2020-05-15 10:56:35 CST; 19min ago
     Docs: https://docs.docker.com
 Main PID: 30521 (dockerd)
    Tasks: 23
   Memory: 39.9M
   CGroup: /system.slice/docker.service
           ├─30521 /usr/bin/dockerd --bip=172.30.184.1/21 --ip-masq=false --mtu=1450 -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock
           └─30941 /usr/bin/docker-proxy -proto tcp -host-ip 0.0.0.0 -host-port 9913 -container-ip 172.30.184.2 -container-port 9913

May 15 10:56:33 log001.example.com dockerd[30521]: time="2020-05-15T10:56:33.927346836+08:00" level=warning msg="Error (Unable to complete atomic operation, key modified) deleting object [endpoint 41febac8f8a0a85733e0b5874a7585621d04d96e1a6bf487d159048ae63feb2f 33633e1f5d07a25926d43f3fe43f73dc201b843c3409bdd57af9386cde0b84f4], retrying...."
May 15 10:56:34 log001.example.com dockerd[30521]: time="2020-05-15T10:56:34.131313757+08:00" level=info msg="Removing stale sandbox d9d1e0cf72283f63c5ac596b3cd59cf6fd9d09d5ddd5db3ae153e94696aea6fb (7b7962f5857ddc5d0a3ca75299e3674dbe0afe4bbfde76f80541e042bf0e11ed)"
May 15 10:56:34 log001.example.com dockerd[30521]: time="2020-05-15T10:56:34.159347847+08:00" level=warning msg="Error (Unable to complete atomic operation, key modified) deleting object [endpoint 41febac8f8a0a85733e0b5874a7585621d04d96e1a6bf487d159048ae63feb2f 605ccd7d57325da3b22b698705fd2e833ee2730455ad74d9fa9bf0ea6a5b8aec], retrying...."
May 15 10:56:34 log001.example.com dockerd[30521]: time="2020-05-15T10:56:34.363895858+08:00" level=info msg="Removing stale sandbox 05d593c66a38608a1a8c90cddfe6510055062497a8844f73a5ddd23d7eee73c0 (ef69a26e96046331af6f2ab17bfc4077581b9fb21a8a65f675ff665cf077ded0)"
May 15 10:56:34 log001.example.com dockerd[30521]: time="2020-05-15T10:56:34.387498628+08:00" level=warning msg="Error (Unable to complete atomic operation, key modified) deleting object [endpoint 41febac8f8a0a85733e0b5874a7585621d04d96e1a6bf487d159048ae63feb2f e67ff48f4e12949f51dfe07841030b9843c929a631fd9178226fb1ac101dbf00], retrying...."
May 15 10:56:34 log001.example.com dockerd[30521]: time="2020-05-15T10:56:34.989648100+08:00" level=info msg="Loading containers: done."
May 15 10:56:35 log001.example.com dockerd[30521]: time="2020-05-15T10:56:35.016351346+08:00" level=info msg="Docker daemon" commit=481bc77 graphdriver(s)=overlay2 version=18.09.6
May 15 10:56:35 log001.example.com dockerd[30521]: time="2020-05-15T10:56:35.016478940+08:00" level=info msg="Daemon has completed initialization"
May 15 10:56:35 log001.example.com dockerd[30521]: time="2020-05-15T10:56:35.028879140+08:00" level=info msg="API listen on /var/run/docker.sock"
May 15 10:56:35 log001.example.com systemd[1]: Started Docker Application Container Engine.
```

seems everything going fine,I am confusing, what should I do to fix it? This is my docker version info:

```
[root@log001 run]# docker version
Client:
 Version:           18.09.6
 API version:       1.39
 Go version:        go1.10.8
 Git commit:        481bc77156
 Built:             Sat May  4 02:34:58 2019
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Experimental:      false
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

I have already read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44678725/cannot-connect-to-the-docker-daemon-at-unix-var-run-docker-sock-is-the-docker), it seems not suite my situation.

Comment: You may need to check if your port 2376 is open

Comment: Make sure you dont have a snap installation that interferes with the classic installation. `sudo snap remove --purge docker`