# Docker is Running But Pycharm Cannot Connect to Docker Daemon

Tags: docker, pycharm

I am new to docker and haven't found a question here to answer the problem I'm experiencing.

I am tryin to use Pycharm to run a dockerfile, in order to debug certain program inside the docker.
I opened the dockerfile in pycharm, and I created a configuration for running the dockerfile.
Running the program results in an error message under the  'services' tab:

```
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

After I Googled the problem, I found this thread: [Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:/var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44678725/cannot-connect-to-the-docker-daemon-at-unix-var-run-docker-sock-is-the-docker)

Which said I should be running `sudo dockerd`. After some bugs I uninstalled docker completely, and installed it again.
After installation I ran:

```
systemctl status docker
```

And the output is:

```
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sat 2020-09-26 15:06:22 IDT; 59s ago
     Docs: https://docs.docker.com
 Main PID: 24888 (dockerd)
    Tasks: 21
   CGroup: /system.slice/docker.service
           └─24888 /usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock
```

So I stopped it using `sudo service docker stop`
I ran `systemctl status docker` again and it was indeed stopped:

```
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) since Sat 2020-09-26 15:09:29 IDT; 16s ago
     Docs: https://docs.docker.com
  Process: 24888 ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock (code=exited, status=0/SUCCES
 Main PID: 24888 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Sep 26 15:06:21 DL-2 dockerd[24888]: time="2020-09-26T15:06:21.919021419+03:00" level=info msg="Loading containers: done."
Sep 26 15:06:22 DL-2 dockerd[24888]: time="2020-09-26T15:06:22.265996712+03:00" level=info msg="Docker daemon" commit=4484c46d9
Sep 26 15:06:22 DL-2 dockerd[24888]: time="2020-09-26T15:06:22.266253446+03:00" level=info msg="Daemon has completed initializa
Sep 26 15:06:22 DL-2 dockerd[24888]: time="2020-09-26T15:06:22.642407513+03:00" level=info msg="API listen on /var/run/docker.s
Sep 26 15:06:22 DL-2 systemd[1]: Started Docker Application Container Engine.
Sep 26 15:09:29 DL-2 systemd[1]: Stopping Docker Application Container Engine...
Sep 26 15:09:29 DL-2 dockerd[24888]: time="2020-09-26T15:09:29.427473508+03:00" level=info msg="Processing signal 'terminated'"
Sep 26 15:09:29 DL-2 dockerd[24888]: time="2020-09-26T15:09:29.428067483+03:00" level=info msg="stopping event stream following
Sep 26 15:09:29 DL-2 dockerd[24888]: time="2020-09-26T15:09:29.428325869+03:00" level=info msg="Daemon shutdown complete"
Sep 26 15:09:29 DL-2 systemd[1]: Stopped Docker Application Container Engine.
```

So I ran `sudo dockerd` and it seemed to run fine:

```
INFO[2020-09-26T15:11:03.918879915+03:00] Starting up                                  
INFO[2020-09-26T15:11:03.919388821+03:00] detected 127.0.0.53 nameserver, assuming systemd-resolved, so using resolv.conf: /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf 
INFO[2020-09-26T15:11:03.919768789+03:00] parsed scheme: "unix"                         module=grpc
INFO[2020-09-26T15:11:03.919779317+03:00] scheme "unix" not registered, fallback to default scheme  module=grpc
INFO[2020-09-26T15:11:03.919792653+03:00] ccResolverWrapper: sending update to cc: {[{unix:///run/containerd/containerd.sock 0  <nil>}] <nil>}  module=grpc
INFO[2020-09-26T15:11:03.919798154+03:00] ClientConn switching balancer to "pick_first"  module=grpc
INFO[2020-09-26T15:11:03.920399082+03:00] parsed scheme: "unix"                         module=grpc
INFO[2020-09-26T15:11:03.920409757+03:00] scheme "unix" not registered, fallback to default scheme  module=grpc
INFO[2020-09-26T15:11:03.920418642+03:00] ccResolverWrapper: sending update to cc: {[{unix:///run/containerd/containerd.sock 0  <nil>}] <nil>}  module=grpc
INFO[2020-09-26T15:11:03.920423441+03:00] ClientConn switching balancer to "pick_first"  module=grpc
INFO[2020-09-26T15:11:04.050458554+03:00] [graphdriver] using prior storage driver: overlay2 
WARN[2020-09-26T15:11:04.212728085+03:00] Your kernel does not support swap memory limit 
WARN[2020-09-26T15:11:04.212780116+03:00] Your kernel does not support cgroup rt period 
WARN[2020-09-26T15:11:04.212798165+03:00] Your kernel does not support cgroup rt runtime 
WARN[2020-09-26T15:11:04.212812782+03:00] Your kernel does not support cgroup blkio weight 
WARN[2020-09-26T15:11:04.212830211+03:00] Your kernel does not support cgroup blkio weight_device 
INFO[2020-09-26T15:11:04.213206856+03:00] Loading containers: start.                   
INFO[2020-09-26T15:11:04.547434099+03:00] Default bridge (docker0) is assigned with an IP address 172.17.0.0/16. Daemon option --bip can be used to set a preferred IP address 
INFO[2020-09-26T15:11:04.985878757+03:00] Loading containers: done.                    
INFO[2020-09-26T15:11:05.259805773+03:00] Docker daemon                                 commit=4484c46d9d graphdriver(s)=overlay2 version=19.03.13
INFO[2020-09-26T15:11:05.259975115+03:00] Daemon has completed initialization          
INFO[2020-09-26T15:11:05.418371093+03:00] API listen on /var/run/docker.sock
```

But running the dockerfile again resulted in the same error. Im quite at a loss as to why this happens, so I would appreciate any feedback.

Should more information be needed, let me know and I'll be happy to provide.
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Can you run docker command such as `docker images` without `sudo`? If not, you should run `sudo usermod -aG docker $USER` and then you can use `docker` command as non-root user (https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/). I'm not sure if it will solve your problem.

Comment: Hi Rui, I ran the command, but when I try without sudo, I get permission denied error. Do you think it would have solved the problem? It sounds to me like a different probelm.

Comment: That means you cannot run docker command as non-sudo user. I guess maybe you run Pycharm as non-root user and have the above problem. So I suggest to run `sudo usermod -aG docker $USER` commend. It can solve the 'non-root' problem and may solve your original one.

Comment: What I meant by my last comment is that even afte running "sudo usermod ...", it doesn't seem to work. But today as a last attempt I ran it and is worked fine. Thank you very much @Rui!

Comment: You also have to login and logout of linux to make the changes take effect

Comment: This, combined with logging out and back in, fixed my instance of this error.

Answer (score 21):

In Docker desktop application on my Mac, under Settings->Advanced I had to enable `Enable default Docker socket (Requires password)` option, after that connection from PyCharm worked.

Comment: I had the same problem in PHPStorm and this fixed it. I guess that setting was changed in a recent Docker Desktop update.

Answer (score 10):

For flatpack users - tested on Pop!_OS:

If you installed PyCharm / PhpStorm / IntelliJ as flatpack image (e.g. via PoP!_Shop):

```
flatpak override --user --filesystem=/var/run/docker.sock com.jetbrains.PyCharm-Community
```

Change the trailing jetbrains product name (here:PyCharm-Community) according to the used version / flavour.

Comment: This is applicable on Manjaro Linux too. Thanks @nash0rn for your answer.

Comment: Worked on Fedora as well

Comment: Note that using /var/run, that is a link to /run, does not work

Comment: @ManuelSchneid3r thanks for the hint, i changed the path accordingly

Answer (score 2):

My problem was the following:

I want to setup debugger in container, but pycharm can't connect to docker daemon.

My environment was:
Ubuntu 22.04
PyCharm professional
Docker Engine v23.0.5

I can run docker commands without sudo, but when try to connect pycharm with docker - have same error `Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?`

So it was pretty easy, I choose docker-desktop in connection menu and ran docker desktop

Comment: This is the same issue i'm having. Could you explain your solution a bit further?

Comment: Hi! Sorry for late response. Is it still actual for you?

Answer (score 0):

Just restart the computer/laptop if other suggestions did not help. It helped me :)

Comment: This worked for me as well. I wonder if just restarting Docker Desktop would have been enough.

Comment: Re-login is enough.

Answer (score 0):

before i installed Pycharm by flatpak from Discover (i use KDE Linux, Discover same like Software Update In Ubuntu). It is main reasion. And then i reinstall Pycharm by tar file in home page of Pycharm. It work for me.