# PyCharm Cannot Connect to Docker, thinks the Docker daemon is not running

Tags: docker, macos, pycharm, docker-daemon

The PyCharm interface to Docker has suddenly stopped working on my Mac. When I try to connect to  Docker I get the error message "Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?".

Docker appears to be working correctly. `docker info` returns reasonable results. The Docker Desktop is running. I can start a container through Docker Desktop and connect to it. Kibana works. The only thing that looks odd is that `/var/run/docker.sock` does not exist.

Is it a problem that `docker.sock` does not exist?

The PyCharm configuration for Docker looks like this:

[image]

I haven't changed it since everything worked.

A common solution suggested online it to change the permissions on the `/var/run/docker.sock` file, but obviously I can't do that. There is an assortment of [things to try](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44678725/cannot-connect-to-the-docker-daemon-at-unix-var-run-docker-sock-is-the-docker), but most of them require sudo and I don't have admin privileges on this machine. There is a Stack Overflow question that [describes the same situation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64077725/docker-is-running-but-pycharm-cannot-connect-to-docker-daemon), but there the problem was that Docker could not be run without sudo, which is not the case here.

What is particularly strange is that this was working just a few days ago, and as far as I know nothing on the machine has changed. Same PyCharm setup, same Docker, same OS. I'm on

- Python Community Edition 2021.2.3
- Docker version 20.10.22, build 3a2c30b
- Mac OSX Ventura 13.1

I have tried restarting the system.

Any ideas on what is broken?

Comment: Did it have anything to do with possibly being clobbered by a recent update to macOS *Ventura* 13.1 which only came out last month?

Comment: Does the command `docker ps` work in Terminal ?

Comment: `docker ps` works. As far as I can tell the command line commands work. I don't know if that means the daemon is running, or what extra thing apps like PyCharm need.

Comment: I think I've had this work since the Ventura upgrade but I'm not sure.

Comment: Try `docker run -it ubuntu bash` If it works, that means docker daemon is running

Comment: `docker run -it ubuntu bash` works. It downloads an Ubuntu image and run a shell inside of it. So I guess `docker.sock` isn't needed to make Docker work?

Comment: Can you post the output of `docker info` ? Did you upgrade to Ventura recently ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem was that `/var/run/docker.sock` did not exist.

More details are in [this Docker support forum thread](https://forums.docker.com/t/is-a-missing-docker-sock-file-a-bug/134351).

This fix was to create the following softlink:

```
ln -s ~/.docker/run/docker.sock /var/run/docker.sock
```

Comment: I was having the same "Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running? (Details: [2] No such file or directory). To fix it change project interpreter or check settings." for PHPStorm. This symlink fixed it. Thanks alot!

Comment: After foraging the internet for answers, this answers just saved me! I couldn't connect to docker from IntelliJ.

Answer (score 2):

You can create the socket file via Docker Desktop's settings.

`Setting` > `Advanced` > `Allow the default Docker socket to be used`

The description of the setting says

> Creates `/var/run/docker.sock` which some third-party clients may use to communicate with Docker Desktop. [Learn more](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/mac/permission-requirements/)

[image]

Comment: This should be the accepted answer