# Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running? (Ubuntu 20.04 ,WSL2)

Tags: windows, docker, docker-compose, ubuntu-20.04, wsl-2

I have ***Microsoft Windows 10 Pro*** version ***10.0.19041 N/A Build 19041*** and I follow steps here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10 to install ***Ubuntu 20.04 LTS*** on it using **WLS2** , I'm doing so to install **docker** by following steps here https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/#install-using-the-repository
but when I try to run `sudo docker run hello-world` it gives me this error *docker: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?.
See 'docker run --help'.* I know that a similar question asked here [Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:/var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44678725/cannot-connect-to-the-docker-daemon-at-unix-var-run-docker-sock-is-the-docker) ,and I try to run `systemctl daemon-reload` and `systemctl start docker` but al the solutions does not worked for me it gives me another errors like *System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
Failed to connect to bus: Host is down* and Also try to fix it but I can't, So I need your help.

**Note :** I have already install Docker in windows and It works fine.

Comment: What does `systemctl status docker` say?

Comment: System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate. Failed to connect to bus: Host is down

Answer (score 3):

I have been solving this problem by following these steps

1. Purge the Grub package Linux command according this issue https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4903
2. Stop Docker Desktop from Windows
3. Run `sudo dockerd` which is the daemon service for Docker containers
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/qgbwE.png
4. Open new Ubuntu shell session
5. Run `docker run hello-world`

and it's work fine with me https://i.stack.imgur.com/6TJ3u.png