# seemingly unsolvable "Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix" (7 solutions tried and failed)

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu, snapcraft

after re-installing docker `sudo snap install docker` on

```sh
francesco@francesco-yoga720:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

```
francesco@francesco-yoga720:~$ docker --version
Docker version 19.03.13, build cd8016b6bc
```

```
francesco@francesco-yoga720:~$ sudo docker pull docker/whalesay
Using default tag: latest
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

---

[edit]

- docker info

```
Client:
 Context:    default
 Debug Mode: false
 Plugins:
  app: Docker App (Docker Inc., v0.9.1-beta3)
  buildx: Build with BuildKit (Docker Inc., v0.5.1-docker)

Server:
ERROR: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
errors pretty printing info
```

- /etc/docker/daemon.json

```
francesco@francesco-yoga720:~$ cat /etc/docker/daemon.json 
cat: /etc/docker/daemon.json: No such file or directory
```

---

as the error seems quite common I try to follow the (many) answers offered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44678725/cannot-connect-to-the-docker-daemon-at-unix-var-run-docker-sock-is-the-docker?page=1&tab=active#tab-top)
but nothing worked

- systemctl start docker (etc)

```
francesco@francesco-yoga720:~$ sudo systemctl start docker
francesco@francesco-yoga720:~$ sudo systemctl enable docker
Synchronizing state of docker.service with SysV service script with /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install.
Executing: /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install enable docker
francesco@francesco-yoga720:~$ sudo systemctl restart docker
francesco@francesco-yoga720:~$ sudo systemctl status docker
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sun 2021-02-21 11:20:43 EET; 1min 53s ago
TriggeredBy: ● docker.socket
       Docs: https://docs.docker.com
   Main PID: 902441 (dockerd)
      Tasks: 13
     Memory: 42.1M
     CGroup: /system.slice/docker.service
             └─902441 /usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock

veebr 21 11:20:42 francesco-yoga720 dockerd[902441]: time="2021-02-21T11:20:42.743739283+02:00" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support CPU realtime scheduler"
veebr 21 11:20:42 francesco-yoga720 dockerd[902441]: time="2021-02-21T11:20:42.743768279+02:00" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support cgroup blkio weight"
veebr 21 11:20:42 francesco-yoga720 dockerd[902441]: time="2021-02-21T11:20:42.743782740+02:00" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support cgroup blkio weight_device"
veebr 21 11:20:42 francesco-yoga720 dockerd[902441]: time="2021-02-21T11:20:42.743999793+02:00" level=info msg="Loading containers: start."
veebr 21 11:20:42 francesco-yoga720 dockerd[902441]: time="2021-02-21T11:20:42.946560909+02:00" level=info msg="Default bridge (docker0) is assigned with an IP address 172.17.0.0/16. Daemon option --bip c>
veebr 21 11:20:43 francesco-yoga720 dockerd[902441]: time="2021-02-21T11:20:43.031108724+02:00" level=info msg="Loading containers: done."
veebr 21 11:20:43 francesco-yoga720 dockerd[902441]: time="2021-02-21T11:20:43.074547710+02:00" level=info msg="Docker daemon" commit=46229ca graphdriver(s)=zfs version=20.10.3
veebr 21 11:20:43 francesco-yoga720 dockerd[902441]: time="2021-02-21T11:20:43.074672376+02:00" level=info msg="Daemon has completed initialization"
veebr 21 11:20:43 francesco-yoga720 systemd[1]: Started Docker Application Container Engine.
veebr 21 11:20:43 francesco-yoga720 dockerd[902441]: time="2021-02-21T11:20:43.122623201+02:00" level=info msg="API listen on /run/docker.sock"

francesco@francesco-yoga720:~$ 
francesco@francesco-yoga720:~$ sudo docker pull docker/whalesay
Using default tag: latest
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

- service docker restart

```
francesco@francesco-yoga720:~$ sudo service docker restart
francesco@francesco-yoga720:~$ sudo docker pull docker/whalesay
Using default tag: latest
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

- sudo snap start docker

```
francesco@francesco-yoga720:~$ sudo snap start docker
Started.
francesco@francesco-yoga720:~$ 
francesco@francesco-yoga720:~$ sudo docker pull docker/whalesay
Using default tag: latest
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

- service docker start

```
francesco@francesco-yoga720:~$ sudo service docker start
francesco@francesco-yoga720:~$ sudo docker pull docker/whalesay
Using default tag: latest
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

- sudo dockerd

```
francesco@francesco-yoga720:~$ sudo dockerd
INFO[2021-02-21T11:26:46.777903160+02:00] Starting up                                  
failed to start daemon: pid file found, ensure docker is not running or delete /var/run/docker.pid
```

- sudo nohup docker daemon (etc)

```
francesco@francesco-yoga720:~$ sudo nohup docker daemon -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375 -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock
nohup: ignoring input and appending output to 'nohup.out'
francesco@francesco-yoga720:~$ sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
francesco@francesco-yoga720:~$ sudo docker pull docker/whalesay
Using default tag: latest
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

EDIT with new attempts:

- sudo rm -rf /var/run/docker.pid

```
francesco@francesco-yoga720:~$ sudo rm -rf /var/run/docker.pid
francesco@francesco-yoga720:~$ sudo docker pull docker/whalesay
Using default tag: latest
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
francesco@francesco-yoga720:~$ sudo snap start docker
Started.
francesco@francesco-yoga720:~$ sudo docker pull docker/whalesay
Using default tag: latest
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

- providing `sudo snap logs docker`

```
francesco@francesco-yoga720:~$ sudo snap logs docker
2021-02-21T11:00:35Z systemd[1]: Started Service for snap application docker.dockerd.
2021-02-21T11:00:36Z docker.dockerd[16902]: time="2021-02-21T13:00:36.204337202+02:00" level=error msg="failed to mount overlay: invalid argument" storage-driver=overlay2
2021-02-21T11:00:37Z docker.dockerd[16902]: failed to start daemon: error initializing graphdriver: driver not supported
2021-02-21T11:00:37Z systemd[1]: snap.docker.dockerd.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
2021-02-21T11:00:37Z systemd[1]: snap.docker.dockerd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
2021-02-21T11:00:37Z systemd[1]: snap.docker.dockerd.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
2021-02-21T11:00:37Z systemd[1]: Stopped Service for snap application docker.dockerd.
2021-02-21T11:00:37Z systemd[1]: snap.docker.dockerd.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
2021-02-21T11:00:37Z systemd[1]: snap.docker.dockerd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
2021-02-21T11:00:37Z systemd[1]: Failed to start Service for snap application docker.dockerd.
```

---

I don't know what else to try, any suggestion?

Comment: Have you tried deleting `/var/run/docker.pid` as told by the output of `sudo dockerd`: `failed to start daemon: pid file found, ensure docker is not running or delete /var/run/docker.pid`?

Comment: Please run "snap logs docker" and investigate logs, also copy it in your post.

Comment: @zsolt thank you for your  quick response, I've updated my question providing the info you requested

Comment: @JustARandomGuyOnTheInternet  thanks for the answer; I tried your solution, but no luck; question updated

Comment: please run "docker info" and share the content of /etc/docker/daemon.json file too.Also tell us what type of filesytsem is your  Root Dir on, shown in "docker info". Are you using ubuntu natively or you use any virtualization or WSL?

Comment: @zsolt I'm using ubuntu natively, I installed docker with snapcraft, I've added docker info about the top of my question, I don't have a /etc/docker/daemon.json

Comment: I guess snapcraft is yet another package manager, but I would advise to go the documented way: https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/

Comment: I'll do that tomorrow, thanks m8