# synology docker Container jenkins build

Tags: spring-boot, docker, gradle, jenkins-pipeline

docker jenkins image will spring boot gralde make docker image in pipeline

when i docker start
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?

or docker build  occur same errors

jenkins docker image os is
Linux jenkins-jenkins1 4.4.180+ #42218 SMP Fri Sep 24 02:41:48 CST 2021 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Debian GNU/Linux 11 \n \l

how to i run docker in jenkins?

Comment: See if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44678725/cannot-connect-to-the-docker-daemon-at-unix-var-run-docker-sock-is-the-docker

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:/var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44678725/cannot-connect-to-the-docker-daemon-at-unix-var-run-docker-sock-is-the-docker)