# Permission error to run docker on linux ubuntu

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu, docker-compose

I followed all the guidelines in the docker documentation to install on my linux ubuntu 22.02, but when trying to give the command

```
sudo docker run hello-world
```

The error is returned to me

```
docker: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?.
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Did you run the docker daemon?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:/var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44678725/cannot-connect-to-the-docker-daemon-at-unix-var-run-docker-sock-is-the-docker)

Comment: The question is, why should I run this docker daemon? In the documentation it doesn't talk about it at any time and also in the tutorial videos that you watch. I do not understand this

Comment: Try to run `systemctl start docker` first

Comment: What would that $USER and password be?

Comment: Docker daemon should be running so you can interact with the service!

Comment: $USER Is your current username variable.

Comment: What can you do without running `ubuntu` os? The same goes to `docker` service

Comment: Yeah, but how do i know my user? At no point did I create any user anywhere from everything the documentation asked me to lol

Comment: `echo $USER` gives you your user...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend that you [configure](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/#configure-docker-to-start-on-boot-with-systemd) Docker to start on boot once you get it started using `systemctl` (i.e. `sudo systemctl start docker`) as others have suggested! Best of luck.

Comment: You can use `enable` for that as in `sudo systemctl enable docker`