# Visual Studio 2017 - Git failed with a fatal error

Tags: git, visual-studio, azure-devops, visual-studio-2017

I am using Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition (CE), and I have signed into my Microsoft account and I am connected to VSTS. I can see all my projects and repositories, but when I attempt to pull/fetch/push any changes I get the following error:

```
Error encountered while pushing to the remote repository: Git failed with a fatal error.
PushCommand.ExecutePushCommand
```

And accordingly for the fetch and pull commands too.

I installed Git for Windows on the Visual Studio 2017 installer and not only is it failing to work with VSTS, I am unable to work with any of my GitHub repositories too. Has anyone else noticed this? It's happened on two of my machines so far.

Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise Edition (EE) and CE work completely fine for me.

It seems that this issue has gotten far more recognition that I thought it would which leads me to believe that this is an issue with how Visual Studio is dealing with Git. I have also noticed that every time I update Visual Studio, this problem pops back up, and I have to go through the steps in some of the answers below to get Git working again. I'm not sure why this is happening, and I also don't know if Microsoft are planning to resolving this issue.

Comment: did u find any solution?

Comment: try going to the solution folder in cmd and using git push to see the actual error, I had the same issue, tried many thing, the command line gave me the actual reason for the failure (I marked my email as private in github and it was conflicting with the push details as it would make my email visible in the code change)

Comment: I was also getting all sorts of errors, fixed them all by just updating the GitHub extension in `Tools > Extensions & Updates`.

Answer (score 140):

After I changed the generic credentials from *Control Panel* → *User Accounts* → *Credential Manager for Git*, it worked for me.

[image]

Comment: This worked for me. Seemed like the easiest of all the suggested solutions too

Comment: Glad it helps. Could you please vote it if it helps? It may help others. Thanks!

Comment: Solved my issue as well. I was getting "Git failed with a fatal error. Authentication failed for <TFS path>". I deleted the git item from Credential Manager and was prompted for my new password next time I tried a push from VS

Comment: Thanks for this. Solved my GIt issue in latest updated VS2017

Comment: I just removed the git links under generic credentials, it worked.

Comment: To get to `Credential Manager` just search for it in windows 10 (use the windows key). Then click Windows Credentials. Scroll down to the Generic Credential section and look for `git: https://your.tfs.server`. I received this error after changing my windows password.

Comment: The location of the credentials is in the `Windows Credentials` section now and not `Web Credentials`. Otherwise the proceeding steps are the same on Windows 10.

Comment: Thanks. Solved my Git issue in VS 2019

Comment: 1. Remove the link as mentioned 
2. RESTART Visual Studio!

Comment: Changed to what?  Can you please clarify?

Comment: Yeah, the answer should really be "After I removed...", not "After I changed..." (if that's what @wbing520 actually did?)

Answer (score 88):

I'm going to add a solution here that the previous answers have not already mentioned, but this is what fixed it for me.

1. Navigate to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\` and delete the `Git` folder.
2. Make sure that there is no version of Git installed on your system, remove it by going to *Control Panel* → *Program and Features* (TortoiseGit does not need to be removed from my experience, just native git installations).
3. Open up the Visual Studio 2017 installer and untick "Git For Windows" in installation options.
4. Head over to the [Git website](https://git-scm.com/) and install the latest version of Git for Windows.
5. Go back into the Visual Studio installer and tick "Git for Windows" again. It will not download a new version even though it may look like it is. After that is done, your Git should be fine with VSTS and TF Explorer.

Comment: I already had git for windows installed. Executing step 1 and step 5 did it for me.

Comment: Ahem - or **Enterprise** instead of **Community** in the above path ;-)

Comment: @Douglas you're absolutely right. I followed what you mentioned. It fixes the problem.

Comment: On Step 4 - does it matter whether one installs 32-bit of 64-bit Git for Windows?

Comment: On Step 4 I used 64-bit Git for Windows and this worked for me.  My VS2017 15.7.3 can once again push to my remote without getting this error.

Comment: Git OpenSSL or native Windows Secure Channel?

Comment: I'm here due to the flashing console windows issue that the steps above fix. Visual Studio 15.9.7 broke Git again, but this fix still works.

Comment: Also had Git already installed, just closed VS deleted git folder, restarted and everything was ok.

Comment: I'm not sure which step fixed the problem, but I did uninstall the older version of git that I had and installed the latest as well as the other steps you mentioned and now it works.

Comment: After HOURS of struggling I finally found my solution here... Thanks a bunch! :D

Comment: For me, all I needed was step 1. (VS 2017 Enterprise, already had git for windows installed.) I exited Visual Studio 2017 first, deleted that GIT folder, then reloaded VS 2017 and all was well. Removed `git` folder from `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer`

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Steps 1 and 5 worked for me for VS 2022. Thank you!

Answer (score 42):

I had a different problem. My computer contained older OpenSSL DLL files in system32 and syswow64 so to fix my problem, I had to copy  `libeay32.dll` and `ssleay32.dll` from one folder to another folder within the Git folders of Visual Studio 2017.

FROM: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\`*vs_edition*`\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\Git\mingw32\bin\`

TO: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\`*vs_edition*`\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\Git\mingw32\libexec\git-core`

Ref.: *[Git - Can't clone remote repository](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/19752/git-cant-clone-remote-repository.html)*

Comment: This worked for me, but where the heck did you find the clue?

Comment: Same trick works for 'Professional', copy the dll's, close VS instances, reopen one and try to close again.

Comment: Those were not the only files that were missing for me. This link describes how to find out what you have to copy. https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/27220/failed-to-push-remote-repository.html

Comment: This may well be the solution we're all looking for!  Thank you!

Comment: Worked for me, Error: `Error encountered while cloning the remote repository: Git failed with a fatal error.
CloneCommand.ExecuteClone`

Comment: Awesome, totally worked - wouldn't have thought of this in a million years - huge kudos!

Comment: @StingyJack I reported the issue to Microsoft together with a Procmon dump, and the supporter from Microsoft identified that it used the wrong dll. 
I never did find out exactly which application I had installed that had put its required version of libeay32.dll/ssleay32.dll in the system32 folder either..

Answer (score 23):

In `Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Credential Manager` ==> `Windows Credentials`
Remove Git:http://........

and Retry..

Enjoy !

Comment: Why do you think that the issue in wrong creds? It will help only in one case but you'll receive another error. Thi doesn't solve problem

Comment: I have no idea why my old credentials stop working (I did not change any credentials), Thanks for saving my day.

Answer (score 17):

I tried a lot and finally got it working with some modification from what I read in *[Git - Can't clone remote repository](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/19752/git-cant-clone-remote-repository.html)*:

1. Modify Visual Studio 2017 CE installation → remove Git for windows (installer → modify → single components).
2. Delete everything from `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\Git`.
3. Modify Visual Studio 2017 CE installation → add Git for windows (installer → modify → single components)
4. Install Git on windows (32 or 64 bit version), having Git in system path configured.

Maybe point 2 and 3 are not needed; I didn't try.

Now it works OK on my Gogs.

Comment: Worked for me, but just after 1 I also uninstalled Git for Windows in the program list for my PC.

Comment: This worked for me. So it looks like the version of Git that MS ships is bad, and replacing it with the official Git for Windows release fixes the problem - just make sure it's in the PATH, and the only version of git that is installed. I think we're finally migrating to VS2017.

Answer (score 11):

This is the error I was getting:

```
Git failed with a fatal error.
pull --verbose --progress --no-edit --no-stat --recurse-submodules=no origin
```

I tried all the previous methods, but they didn't work. Later I found out that there were some conflicts in the code (see the Visual Studio 2017 output window).

*I simply reverted the code and it worked.*

Answer (score 7):

I once had such an error from Git while I was trying to synchronise a repository (I tried to send my commits while having pending changes from my coworker):

> Git failed with a fatal error.
>   pull --verbose --progress --no-edit --no-stat --recurse-submodules=no origin

It turned out that after pressing the <kbd>Commit all</kbd> button to create a local commit, Visual Studio had left one file uncommitted and this elaborated error message actually meant: "Commit all your changes".

That missing file was Entity Framework 6 model, and it is often shown as uncommitted file although you haven't changed a thing in it.

You can do commit all or undo all changes that are not committed.

Comment: Mine was similar to this.  I was having an issue where the newer version of VS 2017 (15.3.2) was all of a sudden constantly making me check in this odd storage.ide file.  I had to keep committing that file after closing/opening VS and that finally worked.  Disclaimer - I also completed the steps in the most accepted answer above as well.

Comment: I just noticed that all files I committed, was still under "Changes". I recommitted them. And problem's gone away.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue. The following steps solved the problem for me:

1. Backup and delete "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\Git"
2. Install latest version of Git: https://git-scm.com/download/win

Comment: I have two machines.  Both have VS2017RTM on them.  Same version of VS and same version of GitHub.VisualStudio.  Neither TeamExplorer folder has a Git folder in it. One works and one doesn't.  :(

Comment: Unbelievable - I deleted the git folder here, but it worked! 

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\Git

Answer (score 5):

This appears to happen in VS 2017 when there is a pending commit that would conflict with the pull. If you go to a command terminal and do a "git pull origin", you will usually get the error that is the source of the confusion. To solve, check in all your changes in VS 2017 and then try the pull or sync again from VS 2017. Needless to say ... this is not desired behavior in VS 2017.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue. **Restarting Visual studio** worked for me... You may try it before reinstalling stuff.

Answer (score 4):

I'm using GitKraken and Visual Studio 2017.

When GitKraken clones a repository, it leaves fetch address like "git@github.com:user/Repo.git", instead of "https://github.com/user/Repo.git".

To fix that, go to *Team Explorer* → *Settings* → *Repository Settings* → *Remotes* → *Edit*, and change "git@" to "https://" **and** ":" to "/".

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem after changing the git access password!

I had to reset the credentials through the PowerShell console.

At the git repository folder level, the script was as follows:

```
git config --system --unset credential.helper

git config --system credential.helper store

git fetch
```

You will be prompted for the user and then the password.

The next command will no longer request authentication:

```
git fetch
```

Answer (score 4):

[image]

When i do pull/fetch/push i got the above error in my output window, i followed the below soloution , it resovled my issue.

If you are using visual studio 2017 enterprise edition, replace the userId with your user id in the below command and execute this command in windows run window(windows key + R).

> runas /netonly /user:UserId "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe"

[image]

This will prompt for password, enter your password. A new visual studio instance will open and will start working properly...

Answer (score 3):

Wow!  There are so many solutions to this problem!

Try this easy one!

**Change your password!**

Just the other day, I started getting this notice that my password would expire in 14 days.  Now 2 days later, I am getting this error:

[image]

I really didn't feel like hacking git or OpenSSL libraries, so I just [changed the Windows password](https://www.google.com/search?q=how%20do%20i%20change%20my%20windows%20password) on my computer and it worked!

**Update**

Then it started happening again.  From **Team Explorer** go to **Sync**.  Then do **Actions > Open Command Prompt**.  In the command prompt type `git push origin`.  That might work for you.

Comment: This seems to be the smartest solution! Thank you ;)

Answer (score 2):

I had a very similar problem and the instructions from a tech at Microsoft fixed it for me:

- Close all instances of Visual Studio.
- Open the Task Manager and check if any TFS Services are running. Select each of them and click on End Process Tree.
- Browse to the folder below and delete all the contents and folders in %LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Team Foundation{version}\Cache
- Go to Control Panel -> User Accounts -> Manage your Credential -> Windows Credential, select the VSTS URL to remove it
- Then go to "C:\Users\USER NAME\AppData\Local\GitCredentialManager\tenant.cache" and delete it
- Also go to "C:\Users\USER NAME\AppData\Local.IdentityService" and delete it

Answer (score 1):

In my case, Windows had ran an update and was waiting to restart the PC. I hadn't seen any notifications but, well... turning it off and turning it on again fixed the problem.

Try that first before monkeying with any of these Visual Studio directories and applications.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue as well. I had sync'd my code earlier in the day so it made no sense that it suddenly gave this Git error. Restarting Visual Studio did not make any difference. After reviewing the above answers and not finding any clear solution, I decided to try syncing outside of Visual Studio using TortoiseGit which I already had installed. This worked. I was then able to sync within Visual Studio normally. If you don't already have TortoiseGit, you may download it (free) from tortoisegit.org.

Comment: VS is incapable of making a new remote origin. This is the only thing that works for me. You do the initial push to the remote on the command line or with Tortoise and then VS can use it.

Answer (score 1):

I got the following error messages using Visual Studio 2017 CE.

> Failed to push to the remote repository. See the Output window for more details.

The output window showed the following:

> Error encountered while pushing to the remote repository: Git process failed unexpectedly.
>   PushCommand.ExecutePushCommand

I tried to push changes using GitHub Desktop. It shows the following error message.

> Cannot push these commits as they contain an email address marked as private on GitHub.

That's It. Solution:

> open GitHub account >> Settings >> Emails >> Uncheck "Keep my email address private"

It's done. That was the problem in my case.

Comment: This was my problem too. I had to uncheck the `Block command line pushes that expose my email` setting, push commits that were pending. Then I configured my GitHub no-reply email address in git global config. Any future commits were then associated with that email and can now be pushed even with the `Block command line pushes that expose my email` turned on again.

Answer (score 1):

I got it working by removing *username@* from http://username@asdf/xxx/yy/zzz.git in the repository settings:

*Team Explorer* → *Settings* → *Repository Settings* → *Remotes* → *Edit*

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix the issue using this line in the command line without reinstalling anything.

git config --global credential.{myserver}.authority NTLM

Simply replace {myserver} with the hostname of your server (without http or port number).

After that, VS was able to connect correctly.

Source: https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows/blob/master/Docs/Faq.md#q-i-thought-microsoft-was-maintaining-this-why-does-the-gcm-not-work-as-expected-with-tfs

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a proxy, open a command prompt and try:

```
git config --global http.proxy <proxy address>:<port>
```

More info at: https://github.com/desktop/desktop/issues/2789

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error pop up in VS 2017 when trying to delete a remote branch. The issue was that the branch was not on the server (using TFS2018 with GIT), but somehow Visual Studio did have it show up in the "remote/origin" section. This meant that I could not delete the remote branch (VS was giving out this error, while the server explorer didn't show up the branch at all).

Here's how to fix it (tested in VS 2017):

1. In Visual Studio, double click on your "rogue" remote branch;
2. VS should have now created a local branch from it;
3. Right click on the local branch, select "Unset remote branch";
4. Right click on the local branch, select "Push branch";
5. You should now have a **true** corresponding remote branch;
6. Delete the remote branch, then the local branch.

Hopefully it will help someone who ends up on this thread having the same issue as me.

Answer (score 1):

I opened Credential Manager in Windows (not Visual Studio), selected "Windows Credentials", found my **git:https//stash....com Generic Credential**, clicked the bubble arrow down to make visible the User name and Password fields with Edit button. Clicked Edit, and put in my **correct password** there. Then started work right after that, no need to close anything.

Answer (score 0):

[AngelBlueSky's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42667928/visual-studio-2017-git-failed-with-a-fatal-error/42668939#42668939) worked partially for me. I had to execute these additional lines to clean the Git global configuration after step 4:

```
git config --global credential.helper wincred
git config http.sslcainfo "C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt"
git config --global --unset core.askpass
git config --global --unset mergetool.vsdiffmerge.keepbackup
git config --global --unset mergetool.vsdiffmerge.trustexitcode
git config --global --unset mergetool.vsdiffmerge.cmd
git config --global --unset mergetool.prompt
git config --global --unset merge.tool
git config --global --unset difftool.vsdiffmerge.keepbackup
git config --global --unset difftool.vsdiffmerge.cmd
git config --global --unset difftool.prompt
git config --global --unset diff.tool
```

Then `git config -l` (executed from any git repo) should return only this:

```
core.symlinks=false
core.autocrlf=false
core.fscache=true
color.diff=auto
color.status=auto
color.branch=auto
color.interactive=true
help.format=html
diff.astextplain.textconv=astextplain
rebase.autosquash=true
user.name=xxxxxxxxxxxx
user.email=xxxxx@xxxxxx.xx
credential.helper=wincred
core.bare=false
core.filemode=false
core.symlinks=false
core.ignorecase=true
core.logallrefupdates=true
core.repositoryformatversion=0
remote.origin.url=https://xxxxxx@bitbucket.org/xxx/xxx.git
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
branch.master.remote=origin
branch.master.merge=refs/heads/master
branch.identityserver.remote=origin
branch.identityserver.merge=refs/heads/identityserver
http.sslcainfo=C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
```

Run the `git status` and `git fetch` commands to validate that it works from the command line.

Then go to Visual Studio, where your repositories should be back, and all sync/push/pull should work without issues.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this issue after I got `wget` from the GNU tools, and copied it right into **c:\windows**. The `libeay.dll` and `libssl.dll` files were also in the archive. When those were in **c:\windows**, I had this issue. Removing them immediately fixed it. So, check if you have these .DLLs somewhere in your path, VS may be picking up some other software's version of these instead of using the ones it expects.

Answer (score 0):

After installing the last version of [Git for Windows](https://git-for-windows.github.io/) you must to open the configuration file to edit:

```
git config --global --edit
```

Click <kbd>Insert</kbd>, remove all the settings, click <kbd>Esc</kbd>, type `:wq` and, <kbd>Enter</kbd> to save.

Now you can clone the repository by Bash or IDE with a valid user.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I didn't have to do anything so drastic as uninstalling Git as per some of the answers here; I just had to use the command line instead of Visual Studio.

Open up `cmd` at your solution's root and enter:

```
git pull
```

You will then be told exactly what the issue is. In my case it told me that I had uncommitted changes that would have been overwritten and that I needed to commit them before I could continue.

Once I had done this the pull succeeded, and I could resolve the conflict in the merge tool.

#### TLDR

Use the command line instead of Visual Studio to get a more complete error message.

Comment: Thank you this solved my issue. I changed my domain username password and before I did, i had uncommitted changes. When used git pull, it shows change username password popup which helped me understand what was the problem. Then I did git reset to lose all the previous change and then it solved my problem in Visual studio

Answer (score 0):

I was getting similar issues. In Visual Studio 2017, with *Rebase* option I solved my issue.

I am having only a master branch. I rebase from master to origin/master (means to the same branch) and clicked *Rebase*. Before doing Rebase, the status was, I was committed my changes however not able to push/sync as my local branch base and Git code base was not synchronised state.

Answer (score 0):

Compounded the problem by deleting the local repo so I could clone a fresh copy. I was faced with new error  **"git cannot be found Git failed with a fatal error.fatal: repository 'xyz' not found"**

I tried everything suggestions i google about with no resolution. 
The following simple step worked for me and I am adding it to the growing list of possible resolutions:

**git config --get http.proxy** result is http://google.com:80

this is not right so i got rid of it.

**git config --global --unset http.proxy**

Answer (score 0):

Try:

Closing all instances of VS and then deleting the account for the TFS server in Control Panel -> User Accounts-> Credentail manager

Refer: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/142173/after-changing-domain-password-couldnt-connect-to.html

Comment: This worked for me. Seemed like the easiest of all the suggested solutions too.

Answer (score 0):

In my case a failing Jest unit test preventing the push to the repo gives the same generic error of "Error encountered while pushing to the remote repository: Git failed with a fatal error."

Answer (score 0):

1. Navigate to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\`
2. Delete the `Git` folder
3. Visual Studio

Answer (score 0):

This problem allways occures to me - when i have to change my password.
It feels like there is allways another problem with my old credentials dont get updated.

1. Go to your Windows Credential Manager
2. Remove all Tfs Credential Entries

Finished

Answer (score 0):

Many solutions here, for me here's what worked.

1. I first changed the credentials from my Windows. In your Windows search, search "Credentials Manager", then go to "Windows Credentials", and updated (Edit option) my password to my new password. (Control Panel → User Accounts → Credential Manager for Visual Studio Git)
2. I restarted Visual Studio, and tried to push, but I still got the "Authentication failed error".
3. I went to back to the Windows Credential manager in step 1 and deleted(Remove option) the GIT account tied to my Visual Studio, I pushed again and it went through.

Answer (score 0):

One tip for those new git users. U need to commit before revert to old code. I tried every solution under this question then I found this stupid stuff by myself. :)

Comment: While committing before reverting does prevent you from losing data, that doesn't answer the OP's question. That would be a good fit for a comment though!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem by uninstalling the 64-bit version and installing a 32-bit version of Git

Answer (score 0):

I got this error while trying clone a new repository. After trying several solutions following worked for me.
From browser Go to dev.azure.com and go to your repo click on Clone and in the IDE select Visual Studio and click on Clone. It will open up visual studio and set the credentials. if it again asks for credentials click on Generate git credentials and use it. Works like a charm.

[image: Close Repository]

Answer (score 0):

I get the following error message when trying to push with the GitHub Extension for Visual Studio:

`Error encountered while pushing branch to the remote repository: Git failed with a fatal error repository 'https://github.com/my-repo' not found`

I know that the repository exists, I pulled from it.
Unfortunately the error message in this situation does not indicate the root cause: I did not have write permissions for that repository

Answer (score 0):

I tried this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/43257818/1831734

But this not solved my problem.
I did following [WINDOWS]

1. Go to repository browser with CMD
2. type: `git push`

Result:
...

```
...
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (11/11), completed with 10 local objects.
remote: error: GH007: Your push would publish a private email address.
remote: You can make your email public or disable this protection by visiting:
remote: http://github.com/settings/emails
To https://github.com/userName/repoName
 ! [remote rejected] main -> main (push declined due to email privacy restrictions)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/userName/repoName'
```

I went to: http://github.com/settings/emails and checked settings then changed my email in Visual Studio/local computer

**Setting your email address for every repository on your computer**

1. Open Git Bash.
2. Set an email address in Git. You can use your GitHub-provided no-reply email address or any email address.

   `$ git config --global user.email "email@example.com"`
3. Confirm that you have set the email address correctly in Git:

   `git config --global user.email email@example.com`

   Add the email address to your account on GitHub, so that your commits are attributed to you and appear in your contributions graph. For more information, see "Adding an email address to your GitHub account."
4. Reset the author information on your last commit:

   `git commit --amend --reset-author`

Answer (score 0):

1. Install or Update VS 2019 (reboot if needed).
2. Open the Visual Studio Installer and uninstall "Git for Windows".
3. Delete the following folder entirely (and all it's contents):

   ```
   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\Git\
   ```
4. Open the Visual Studio Installer again and install "Git for Windows".
5. The folder you deleted in step 3 did not come back and Git for Windows should be installed in `C:\Program Files\Git\`.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this with simple solution.

1. Go to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\Git\mingw32\ssl\certs
2. Open file - ca-bundle.trust.crt
3. After opening Certificate window, click on Install Certificate.

Now try to clone repository.

Answer (score -1):

If it doesn't work from *Team* → *Manage Connections* → *Local Git Repositories* → *Clone*, one can try either one these two ways.

Menu *File* → *Start Page* → *Open* → *Go for Git*

*(or)*

Menu *File* → *Open* → *Open from source control*

Answer (score -2):

The below fixes my problem.

1. Navigate to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\`
   and delete the Git folder.

   Make sure that there is no version of Git installed on your system,
   remove it by going to *Control Panel* → *Program and Features*
   (TortoiseGit does not need to be removed from my experience, just
   native Git installations).
2. Open up the Visual Studio 2017 installer and untick "Git For Windows" in installation options.
3. Head over to the Git website and install the latest version of Git for Windows.
4. Go back into the Visual Studio installer and tick "Git for Windows" again. It
       will not download a new version even though it may look like it is.
       After that is done, your Git installation should be fine with VSTS and TF
       Explorer.

Comment: Re *TF Explorer*: Do you mean *Team Explorer*?

Comment: Worked fine for me by only doing the first step, then it used the correct version of the GIT software

Answer (score -3):

**Understand Why are you getting this error** : if you are able to delete your other branches but not another branch, then there is a case that you are not the owner of that branch, ie. the branch has been created by some one else and you are using it.

**Easy Solution** : **you can ask the owner of the branch to delete it** !! simple:)

**Problem faced**: Error encountered while deleting branch from the remote repository: PushCommand.ExecutePushCommand