# Visual Studio 2017 push error on TFS (visual studio online with GIT)

Tags: git, tfs, visual-studio-2017

I move to VS17 from VS15 when i try to push my changes to TFS Online I get this error

> Error encountered while pushing to the remote repository: Git failed
>   with a fatal error.

If I close and move back to VS15 I reopen the same repository I'm able to push it.  Another strange situation is that on Team Explorer window my solution is not show reather then VS15 and I need to open manualy.

Comment: What's the result if you push via git command directly? (git push) On the other hand, try to clone the repository through VS 2017 and do other actions and check result.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VS 2017 - Git failed with a fatal error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42667928/vs-2017-git-failed-with-a-fatal-error)

Answer (score 0):

This works for me with VS2017 RTM

1. Uninstall any current version of Git for Windows
2. Install Git using [Web Platform Installer](https://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx)
3. Open Command Prompt 
   [via Visual Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AKYLJ.png)
4. Executing set HOMEPATH in the command line gave this output:

Update:
Some people still facing this issue even after the VS2017 little update, but Microsoft is aware of it and currently working on it https://twitter.com/VisualStudio/status/841803379231887360

Comment: I tried to push also to TFS Onlne, however, it only pushed .vs and .sou files, none of the source files were pushed to TFS Online.  Is there a similarity with this issue?