# Unable to sync changes with Visual Studio Git plugin

Tags: git, visual-studio, github, visual-studio-2017

I am using Visual Studio 2017 and trying to sync push my local changes to remote repository using Git plug-in in VS 2017.
I staged my changes and committed them. Now when I try to push the changes I get below error-

> Error encountered while pushing to the remote repository: rejected
>   Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
>   its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes  before pushing
>   again.

So I tried to fetch and pull the latest changes from the remote repository first. The fetch succeeded but when I pull the incoming commits it gives below error-

> Error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten
>   by merge: Error: merging of trees
>   73d9f5683703dbb7dede45aa858a9dc46a156f07 and
>   e59a44271f3ae2b73e397cdade39d4270e7a773c failed

Ideally a pull should fetch and merge the changes. I tried searching for some resolution and came across this link- [VS 2017 - Git failed with a fatal error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42667928/vs-2017-git-failed-with-a-fatal-error)

This solution did not work for me. Any ideas how can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While [`git stash`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash) is not yet (Q4 2017) available for Visual Studio (see [this uservoice](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/4576531-provide-stash-support-in-visual-studio-tools-for-g)), you can still stash your currently modified files in command line:

```
cd /path/to/your/repo
git stash
```

Then your git pull can proceed. Type `git stash pop` to get back your current changes.