# Fatal error while cloning repository from Azure DevOps

Tags: git, visual-studio-2017, azure-devops

Please don't count this question as Possible duplicate, though the problem already exists. I am getting an error while cloning the repository(git) from Azure DevOps. I have seen, the same type of problem already exist in StackOverflow or other blogs. here are few links which are associated with my problems and I have followed:

[Unable to change git account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46629838/unable-to-change-git-account/46679813)

[Visual Studio 2017 - Git failed with a fatal error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42667928/visual-studio-2017-git-failed-with-a-fatal-error)

But the error still available while I am cloning the repository using VS 2017 Team Explorer.

```
Git failed with a fatal error.
unable to access 'https://sebu.visualstudio.com/Angular/_git/Angular/': Failed to connect to sebu.visualstudio.com port 443: Timed out
```

Comment: Which VS 2017 version exactly do you use? Did you success to clone the repo locally in cmd?

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk Visual Studio Community 2017 (15.9.4). Yes, I have tried to clone using cmd, but same error.

Comment: Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk no.

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk No proxies were detected using this site http://www.whatismyproxy.com/

Answer (score 0):

```
unable to access 'https://test.visualstudio.com/Angular/_git/Angular/': 
Failed to connect to sebu.visualstudio.com
```

Considering the domain name changes, check if you have in your configuration any [url..insteadOf](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-urlltbasegtinsteadOf) rule:

```
git config -l
```

If there is any url."sebu.visualstudio.com".insteadOf rule, that would explain why test is changed into sebu.

Answer (score 0):

i have been working on this for several days and I finally managed to crack it. 
1. select clone in vscode
2. it will ask you to open on new vscode window so click yes
3. head over to devOps and click on generate git credentials
4. copy the long password and paste it in upper password field prompt in vscode

this worked for me so well, happy coding?

Comment: What do you mean by `select clone`?

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this problem. I do not know the exact cause of this problem, but I solved this problem using a VPN