# When trying to "Commit all and Sync" an error pops up: "Git failed with a fatal error."

Tags: c#, git, visual-studio-2019

I worked for a while on a WebApp (c#, .NET framework 4.5) and wanted it to upload to git(Commit all and sync). Mind you, I've done this a few times already, and this is the first time this error pops up.
This is the error:

> Git failed with a fatal error.
>   warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in Test2/packages/bootstrap.3.4.1/content/Content/bootstrap-theme.css.
>   The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
>   warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in Test2/packages/bootstrap.3.4.1/content/Content/bootstrap-theme.min.css.

Is there any workaround or a quick fix?

EDIT: [Visual Studio 2017 - Git failed with a fatal error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42667928/visual-studio-2017-git-failed-with-a-fatal-error) I've seen this thread. This does not solve my problem it is different.

EDIT2: I probably found the reason why it may have occured: I linked a database to this app and that may have caused this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio 2017 - Git failed with a fatal error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42667928/visual-studio-2017-git-failed-with-a-fatal-error)

Comment: These are the warning, not the fatal error itself

Comment: @Davide Quaglio it's what the error/warning said. I did not make it up myself.

Comment: @JuliaP. that doesn't change the fact that those are warnings. `Commit` and `Sync` are different operations though. Commit is something you'd do multiple times per day. Not as frequently as *saving*, but close. Pushing/pulling  the commited changes is something that's done relatively infrequently. Have you tried commiting the changes first?

Comment: @JuliaP. yes, I was just stating that the 2 warning are not the cause of the fatal error. Maybe you could try to download the latest version of git, maybe it will help. Also you could try to open VS installer and remove, then re-add the options for git

Comment: What happens if you do a `git pull` or `git push` from the command line?