# Visual Studio 2019 - Clone Git failed with a fatal error. Repository not found

Tags: git, visual-studio-2019

I am trying for the first time to download a Git repository to Visual Studio 2019 using VS Clone. I am getting

```
Cloning into 'C:\Users\Charles\Source\Repos\FingerprintGuide'...
Error encountered while cloning the remote repository: Git failed with a fatal error.
repository 'https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/tree/master/FingerprintGuide/' not found
```

The folder certainly exists as anyone can verify. I am signed into Git from a Web browser outside of Visual Studio. Visual Studio  Git Options has my correct Git user name and e-mail.

What might I be doing wrong? As I say, I am new to Git, so it might be something obvious.

Comment: You can have a look at similar issue : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42667928/visual-studio-2017-git-failed-with-a-fatal-error

Comment: Thanks. I tried the 5-step program detailed there. Still getting same error.

Comment: My gosh. There are about fifty different "try this/try that/delete OpenSSL" ideas there. What is a poor user supposed to do?

Comment: I think that's because you have a bad url that should only be `https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples`

Comment: Thank you, yes, that did it. Although I now have almost a gigabyte more of stuff than I actually wanted.

Comment: For that, you should do a shallow clone or a partial clone (or both) depending on what you want to achieve : https://github.blog/2020-12-21-get-up-to-speed-with-partial-clone-and-shallow-clone/

Comment: Thanks, yeah, I really need to learn git.

Comment: What is *"VS Clone"*? A menu command? Is it literal? Or really a common noun? Something else?

Comment: Today I came across this very same issue while trying to clone a Git repo. If anyone managed to fix this please reply.

Answer (score 5):

Clear credentials solve my problem, thanks for Kayla Ngan who proposed the solution

In the Windows search, type "Credential Manager". Choose "Windows Credentials", then clear the creds for the specific "git:{URL}". Then try cloning again.

ref: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/git-failed-with-a-fatal-error-repostiory-not-found/156101#T-N179991

Answer (score 3):

You have to customize some setting in Visual Studio to clone properly.

1. Continue without code in the start page of Visual Studio
2. Go to the Git menu in Visual Studio
3. Go to *Settings*
4. Search for source control in the left tree view
5. Select *Git Global Settings*
6. Then set the setting as shown:

   [image: Git settings for Visual Studio]

And then try to clone again. Before cloning, delete the destination or make the destination folder empty in your local machine to which you are cloning into.

Answer (score 1):

Remove all **azure, git, github, VisualStudio, vs code** ***"windows credential"***.

Watch this **video** :
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y6qLNgFt1EM

Answer (score 0):

My primary Browser Chrome had old credentials stored for my personal account.  So VS authenticated using those, instead of my work account.  Delete from Google Password Manager old github credentials.