# git add -A, permission denied

Tags: git, permission-denied

this is what I am getting:

```
Saras-MacBook-Pro:ruby-project saraginsburg$ git add -A
error: open("vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/byebug-5.0.0/ext/byebug/siteconf20170512-623-1pgx7y0.rb"): Permission denied
error: unable to index file vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/byebug-5.0.0/ext/byebug/siteconf20170512-623-1pgx7y0.rb
fatal: adding files failed
```

Answer (score 2):

Similarly to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6400755/6309), double-check your right (permission) to `vendor/bundle` folder.

But more importantly, ask yourself if you should version anything from `vendor/bundle` in the first place: that folder (`vendor/`) should be part of your `.gitignore` anyway.